# PHP cURL vs file_get_contents

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

How do these two pieces of code differ when accessing a REST API?

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?login=user&apiKey=key&longUrl=url');
```

and

```
$ch = curl_init('http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?login=user&apiKey=key&longUrl=url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

They both produce the same result, judging by

```
print_r(json_decode($result))
```

Comment: `cURL` is capable of much more than `file_get_contents`. That should be enough.

Comment: FWIW there's little difference with regards to speed. I've just finished fetching 5,000 URLs and saving their HTML to files (about 200k per file). I did half with curl and half with file_get_contents as an experiment and there was no discernible difference.

Comment: It is possible to send post data with file_get_contents, as long as you are using a version that supports stream context.

Comment: I prefer file_get_contents because of its simplicity, but I'm frequently unable to use it if allow_url_fopen is turned off in server configurations that I have no control over. So for that reason alone I recommend cURL with a possible function_exists('curl_init') check and if that doesn't pass a fallback to file_get_contents.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` is a simple screwdriver. Great for simple GET requests where the header, HTTP request method, timeout, cookiejar, redirects, and other important things do not matter.

`fopen()` with a [stream context](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) or cURL with [setopt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) are powerdrills with every bit and option you can think of.

Comment: To stay within that metaphor, note that cURL is a powerdrill with a complicated drill chuck that requires you to know it pretty well to actually change it (read: setting cURL options is a bit tedious, but allows for doing anything you want).

Comment: `file_get_contents` allows also to set the context, which means you can set the header fields as you like.

Comment: and as addition to @velop's comment, through the stream context it is also possible to send POST, PUT, authentication, headers, content, proxy, and much more with one file_get_contents request

Comment: @velop: Yes. And method, too. And redirects. And timeout... http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

Answer (score 31):

In addition to this, due to some recent website hacks we had to secure our sites more. In doing so, we discovered that *file_get_contents* failed to work, where *curl* still would work.

Not 100%, but I believe that this php.ini setting may have been blocking the *file_get_contents* request.

```
; Disable allow_url_fopen for security reasons
allow_url_fopen = 0
```

Either way, our code now works with *curl*.

Comment: Yes, `file_get_contents` requires `allow_url_fopen` to be truthy.

Comment: Yes, many hosting companies are disabling `file_get_contents()` due to many exploits that are known to use the function. cURL is the function people should be using in code now.

Comment: @frustratedtech What "exploits" are these?

Comment: Hosting companies disable `allow_url_fopen` because they kind of mistake it for `allow_url_include`. `allow_url_fopen` and `file_get_contents` are fine to use.

Comment: @rdlowrey, http://curl.haxx.se/docs/vulnerabilities.html
https://blog.cloudflare.com/inside-shellshock/

Comment: @vr_driver those links have nothing to do with `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Yes, hosting companies disable allow_url_fopen because of exploits.  The typical use case of file_get_contents is to read a local file.  But if you can find a way to override the filename and pass a URL instead, then you can read a REMOTE file instead (and it could be a file whose contents you control...)  I understand the need to keep this box locked shut.  file_get_contents should not have been given this magical power in the first place - it should have been a separate function.

Comment: @jdhildeb it is not a "magical power", nor an obscure use case, as evidenced by "Example #1 Get and output the source of the homepage of a website", it is simply a wrapper for fopen(). if you can find a way to override the filename and pass a URL instead, you are either ignoring or in dire need of basic security practice

Answer (score 27):

This is old topic but on my last test on one my API, cURL is faster and more stable. Sometimes file_get_contents on larger request need over 5 seconds when cURL need only from 1.4 to 1.9 seconds what is double faster.

I need to add one note on this that I just send GET and recive JSON content. If you setup cURL properly, you will have a great response. Just "tell" to cURL what you need to send and what you need to recive and that's it.

On your exampe I would like to do this setup:

```
$ch =  curl_init('http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?login=user&apiKey=key&longUrl=url');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

This request will return data in 0.10 second max

Comment: 0.1 MICROseconds (1/1,000 of a MILIseconds) ... I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Yes. I have some responses in 0.02ms for example Twilio API phone number check. Is fast.

Comment: 0.02ms = 20 microseconds; you said 0.1 microseconds which can't be right.

Comment: This is almost twice as fast compare to `file_get_contents ` I just did some API calls to confirm. 0.8 seconds for `file_get_contents` & 0.49 seconds for `curl` (3 API calls)

Comment: You should use your own setup. Then your queries would go from 1.4-1.9s to 0.01s ;)

Answer (score 7):

I know it is an old topic but I believe this is really important. And now, there are a lot of differences more than 8 years ago. As we all know, [Curl](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/tree/9.8.0) is 3rd part library.

> **Simple Comparison**: Last version of Curl library has more than 170 different functions to be able to send proper request to APIs. There
> were only 70 functions 8 years ago. **Fact**: still under development.

That's why I wanted to put a new comment to this question.

#### What is file_get_contents()

[file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is a filesystem function in PHP that you can read contents from a file and make requests using GET and POST methods. You can add parameters to your request while you're using file_get_contents() function. You can see the sample below.

```
$data = http_build_query(
    array(
        'user_id'   => '558673',
        'user_name' => 'John Doe'
    )
);

$config = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $data
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($config);

$result = file_get_contents('https://google.com', false, $context);
```

#### What is curl()

[Curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) is open source third party library. You can reach the git repo from [here](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class). This function "**simulates**" HTTP requests and responses. This simulation allows you handling async HTTP requests and complex data transfers. In addition, Curl is suitable for performing cross-domain based FTP request. It can be used in various apps like data crawling from a website and proxy setup.

Let's check a CURL request syntax.

```
$url = API_ENDPOINT."/get_movies";
        
  $curl = curl_init();
         
  $params = array(
    'category' => $category,
    'limit' => $limit,
    'start' => $start,
    'order' => $order,
    'term' => $term
  );

  $params_string = http_build_query($params);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params_string);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  
  $data = curl_exec($curl);     
  curl_close($curl);

  echo json_decode($data,TRUE); //service returns json in this sample
```

**Note:** This is the basic sample of a curl request. You can add more parameter and options to the curl object using its functions like CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER. These kind of parameters all up to you and the service that you trying to use.

### CURL vs file_get_contents()

- `CURL` is able to handle complex HTML communications, but
  `file_get_contents()` is not.
- `CURL` supports HTTP PUT, GET, POST but
  `file_get_contents()` supports simple HTTP GET and HTTP POST
  requests.
- `CURL` supports caching and cookies but
  `file_get_contents()` doesn’t support caching, cookies, etc.
- `CURL` is able to use HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, FTPS and [more](https://everything.curl.dev/protocols/curl).
  `file_get_contents()` uses HTTP and HTTPS protocols for
  communications.
- `CURL` can be used to read, update and delete files
  from server, but `file_get_contents()` only allows you to read a
  file.
- `CURL` is more secure and faster than `file_get_contents()`
- `CURL` is bit more complex to understand than `file_get_contents()`.