# Multiquery : Returns empty array

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
$queries = '{"query1":"SELECT pid, src, link, caption, like_info, created FROM photo WHERE aid in ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = me() AND type = \"profile\" AND name = \"Profile Pictures\" ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 1)","query2":"SELECT pid, src, link, caption, created, like_info FROM photo WHERE aid in ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = me() AND type = \"profile\" AND name = \"Profile Pictures\" ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1)"}';    
$multiquery = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.multiquery?queries=" . urlencode($queries) . "&format=json&" . $access_token;
$res = json_decode(file_get_contents($multiquery), TRUE);
```

But when execute a two single queries, it is working fine. What is the problem here?

I am just trying to fetch the first and the last profile photo

Comment: Is this completely a wrong a question? I am still trying. But i didnt get anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

The best way to do this is with the [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php) and not with `file_get_contents`.

You are using the old REST API url, which is deprecated. You should be using the Graph API url: `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=`

Does your `$access_token` variable include the `&access_token=` piece of the query string?

Finally, to keep your queries straight, I've found the best way is to add these as elements of an array with the query name as the key, e.g.: `$fql['query1'] = 'SELECT ...'` and then use `json_encode(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $fql))` to combine them into error-free json.

Comment: Can you post any simple example of multiquery which is not deprecated? you are telling fql?q=. Is it not for an ordinary fql?

Comment: The path `/fql?q=` works for both a single query and a multiquery. Here's a complete working example for you: http://pastebin.com/edA0sMHF I kept `file_get_contents()` here for brevity only. If this were production code, I'd be using the PHP SDK or cURL.

Comment: why cant' we use file_get_contents?

Comment: See this article for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064980/php-curl-vs-file-get-contents