# How to check if Image exists on server using URL

Tags: php

I am trying to check whether image file is exist on server Or not. I am getting image path with other server.

Please check below code which I've tried,

`$urlCheck = getimagesize($resultUF['destination']);`

```
if (!is_array($urlCheck)) {
  $resultUF['destination'] = NULL;
}
```

But, it shows below warning

```
Warning: getimagesize(http://www.example.com/example.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in
```

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: you need to give absolute path like "images/example.jpg"

Comment: @MakC Did any of the answers helped?

Comment: @sankalpMishra yes i tried with below answers but due to allow_url_fopen it shows warnings on server SO then i have tried using CURL and it works for me.

Comment: @PravinS I can not use absolute path coz my image files are on another server and my code is on another server

Comment: @MakC use get_headers() function, it will return you length, http response and more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) function

```
if (@fopen($resultUF['destination'], "r")) {
    echo "File Exist";
} else {
    echo "File Not exist";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/example.jpg)';
print_r(get_headers($url));
```

It will give an array. Now you can check the response to see if image exists or not

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that the file is exist regularly on server or not.you should used:

[is_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)   .For example

$url="http://www.example.com/example.jpg";

```
if(is_file($url))
{
echo "file exists on server";
}
else
{
echo "file not exists on server ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fastest & efficient Solution for broken or not found images link** 
i recommend you that don't use getimagesize() because it will 1st download image then it will check images size+if this will not image then it will throw exception so use below code

```
if(checkRemoteFile($imgurl))
{
//found url, its mean
echo "this is image";
}

function checkRemoteFile($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // don't download content
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if(curl_exec($ch)!==FALSE)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note:**
this current code help you to identify broken or not found url image this will not help you to identify image type or headers

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that the image **may not exist** or you don't have a **direct permission** for accessing the image, else you must be pointing an **invalid location** to the image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `file_get_contents`. This will cause php to issue a warning along side of returning `false`. You may need to handle such warning display to ensure the user interface doesn't get mixed up with it.

```
 if (file_get_contents($url) === false) {
       //image not foud
   }
```

Comment: It is more recommended to use curl method instead of file_get_contents because the 2nd one is really slow compared to the curl. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064980/php-curl-vs-file-get-contents