# How do I send a GET request with a header from PHP?

Tags: php, http, curl, header, get

Call me out if this is a duplicate question, but this is starting to get ridiculous.
I want to, with PHP:

```
 GET http://www.example.com/hello.xyz
```

And  add this header to the request:

```
 "X-Header-Name: $foobar"
```

where foobar comes from a php variable that is already defined.

and then store the response in a variable. That's it! Nothing more, nothing less.
But I can't find it!
<s>I don't want to use curl or anything like that, it'd slow it down too much if I run curl everytime.</s> **Edit: My main concern with using curl is about compatibility with Windows (local server) vs. Linux (deployment server).**

```
<?php

echo "So, how do I do it in the simplest way possible?";

?>
```

Comment: A library like curl is the simplest way possible. *Any* library you use is likely to "slow down" script execution, as it's the request itself that takes the time. Googling `How do I send a GET request with a header from PHP?` gets 2 good results that show how

Comment: If you don't want to use curl for performance reasons, you have to implement and measure it in curl. Where is your code that is too slow?

Comment: Why not use cURL? It will also give you a lot more functionality for handling errors and such.  Also, if you are concerned about making a large number of requests in a short timeframe, you can execute parallel requests using `curl_multi_exec()`, which should allow your script to execute much more quickly then doing a bunch of serial `shell_exec()` commands or whatever. I have a nice lightweight `curl_multi_exec()` REST client at https://github.com/mikecbrant/php-rest-client you can feel free to use.

Comment: You can use the socket functions in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php.  You just have to do all the things the cURL lib does, manually.

Comment: Oh, I thought that I'd be running a lot of subprocesses from PHP. A concern of mine is that I'll have to deal with compatibility issues if/when I switch to Windows for local testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) if you don't want to use [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) but not sure about speed but it's `php`'s built in function where `curl` is not. When talking about `speed` then I think whatever you use for a remote request, the speed/performance will depend on the network connection speed more than the function/library and maybe there is a bit different among these (curl/file_get_contents/fsockopen) but I think it'll be a very little (1-2 %) and you can't catch the difference, it'll seem almost same.

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
      'method'=>"GET",
      'header'=>"X-Header-Name: $foobar"
));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/hello.xyz', false, $context);
if($data) {
    // do something with data
}
```

Also, if you want to use `curl` then you may use this

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Header-Name: $foobar"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/hello.xyz");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($curl_errno == 0) {
    // $data received in $data
}
```

Also, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064980/php-curl-vs-file-get-contents), it may help you to decide.