# PHP Using cURL and GET request with a header

Tags: php, curl, get, line-api

There are slimier questions in the past like below.

[How do I send a GET request with a header from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259490/how-do-i-send-a-get-request-with-a-header-from-php)

But I don't know why my code is not working.
I want to get "status code 200 OK and image data in binary" by using cURL and GET request with a header.

I may make mistake on debugging too. 
I would appreciate your any help.
Thanks in advance!

API refrence: https://devdocs.line.me/en/#get-content

```
$url = "https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/". $message_id. "/content";
$curl = curl_init("$url");
error_log(var_export($curl));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // 証明書の検証を行わない
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$image_binary = substr($response, $header_size);
curl_close($curl);

error_log(print_r("xxx...",true));
error_log(var_export($response));
error_log(print_r("aaa...",true));
error_log(print_r($response,true));
error_log(print_r("bbb...",true));
error_log(print_r($header,true));
error_log(print_r("ccc...",true));
error_log(print_r($image_binary,true));
```

Then.. I get this...

```
2017-01-01T01:04:48.272544+00:00 app[web.1]: [01-Jan-2017 10:04:48 Asia/Tokyo] 
2017-01-01T01:04:48.911005+00:00 app[web.1]: [01-Jan-2017 10:04:48 Asia/Tokyo] xxx...
2017-01-01T01:04:48.911023+00:00 app[web.1]: [01-Jan-2017 10:04:48 Asia/Tokyo] 
2017-01-01T01:04:48.911063+00:00 app[web.1]: [01-Jan-2017 10:04:48 Asia/Tokyo] aaa...
2017-01-01T01:04:48.911125+00:00 app[web.1]: [01-Jan-2017 10:04:48 Asia/Tokyo] ����
2017-01-01T01:04:48.911165+00:00 app[web.1]: [01-Jan-2017 10:04:48 Asia/Tokyo] bbb...
2017-01-01T01:04:48.911201+00:00 app[web.1]: [01-Jan-2017 10:04:48 Asia/Tokyo] ����
2017-01-01T01:04:48.911239+00:00 app[web.1]: [01-Jan-2017 10:04:48 Asia/Tokyo] ccc...
2017-01-01T01:04:48.911273+00:00 app[web.1]: [01-Jan-2017 10:04:48 Asia/Tokyo] ��
```

Comment: Using `print_r` is insufficient information to know the type. Consider using `var_export` or `var_dump` or even `json_encode`, which will help show the data type. Also, you didn't dump your `$response`.

Comment: `CURLOPT_POST, false` is not necessary.

Comment: Are you sure you want to put the `, true` behind the closing parenthesis for `var_export`?

Comment: I deleted ".true" but can't get any result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PHP documentation for `CURLOPT_HEADER`:

> **TRUE** to include the header in the output.

Your `$response` will probably look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Some: headers
More: header lines

{
    "real": "json content"
}
```

This is because you added the [`CURLOPT_HEADER`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADER.html) option.

You don't need to set any options to let the curl request send your headers. As long as you set the [`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html) option, the headers will be sent.

If you really want to receive the response headers too, check existing questions like [*"Can PHP cURL retrieve response headers AND body in a single request?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9183272/3990767)

Comment: Ive deleted "CURLOPT_HEADER" but still can't get a Json.

Comment: Dump your `$response` to see if you have got what you expected, and use `json_last_error_msg` to see the exact error.

Comment: Ive tried "error_log(print_r("error is : ".json_last_error(),true));".     The result is "5."  Does this mean, JSON_ERROR_UTF8??

Comment: Print your `$response`, then you will see what is wrong with the JSON...

Comment: Thanks for your help! Ive modified my post and result!

Comment: I've modifed my code again referring to your link. Could you check it? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use `error_log(print_r(...), true)` instead of `error_log(print_r(..., true))`...

Comment: I don't know what happened but it started working! Anyway, I really appreciate your help!