# Using cURL GET statement in PHP

Tags: php, curl, get

I have a cURL GET statement:

```
curl -v -X GET "https://admiraltyapi.azure-api.net/uktidalapi/api/V1/Stations/{stationId}" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {subscription key}" --data-ascii "{body}"
```

that works fine in a terminal window (with my sub key) - I now want to use it in a PHP script to retrieve the associated JSON. Code suggestions for achieving this appreciated...

Comment: SO is not a coding service ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396724/php-using-curl-and-get-request-with-a-header may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you need something like this with PHP CURL.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://admiraltyapi.azure-api.net/uktidalapi/api/V1/Stations/{stationId}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT, true);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {subscription key}';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: @Jeff Glad it helps you somehow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Just one last question: I need to add --data-ascii "{body} after the sub key but that is proving difficult to figure out! Grateful if you can help again...

Comment: its OK, I sorted the last bit. Thanks again Sunny!

Comment: If my answer helps you then you should vote it up and mark it as answer mate :)