# Scrape and Extract data from https://chenmed.wd1.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/jencare/ when it is not visible in the 'Source Code' of the webpage

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-crawler, data-extraction

I am trying to write an automated PHP script to scrape and extract all 'Job Titles' (Primary Care Physician - Tidewater Market, Primary Care Physician - Richmond Market etc.) from URL https://chenmed.wd1.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/jencare/

However, this does not seem to be straightforward because the required data is not directly visible in the source code of the webpage. I also tried inspecting 'Developer Tools->Network' of different browsers, however could not locate the source of the data.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards!

Comment: not related, but PhantomJS might handle this lot easier in my point of view.

Comment: Maybe they want to protect their sources?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the requests made by the website one notices an XHR request that contains the data you care about:

[image]

However visiting that URL in a browser gives the same result as navigating to https://chenmed.wd1.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/jencare/. Investigating further by looking at the request headers

[image]

one notices the `Accept:application/json,application/xml` (which signifies that the client expect a json or xml document). Indeed it turns out to be true that requesting https://chenmed.wd1.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/jencare/ with this additional header returns the desired data:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> req = urllib.request.Request('https://chenmed.wd1.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/jencare/')
>>> req.add_header('Accept', 'application/json,application/xml')
>>> urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8').find('Primary Care Physician ') > 0
True
```

Therefore in PHP you probably want to do the following steps:

1. Request ttps://chenmed.wd1.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/jencare/ with the additional header `Accept:application/json,application/xml` (see e.g. [How do I send a GET request with a header from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259490/how-do-i-send-a-get-request-with-a-header-from-php))
2. Parse the returned JSON (e.g. using http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks @Jonathan