# How to execute API link of another website in PHP

Tags: php, http, curl

I want to call the API URL of another website in PHP file.
The URL is:

http://otherwebsite.com/api/web2sms.php?workingkey=YourKey&to=DestinationNumber&sender=Source&message=HELLO

**My code:**

```
<?php

$workingkey = "YourKey";
$to = "DestinationNumber";
$sender = "Source";
$message = "HELLO";

$url = "http://otherwebsite.com/api/web2sms.php?workingkey=$workingkey&to=$to&sender=$sender&message=$message";

$this = execute($url);
?>
```

I think many things are missing. So please tell me how to make a susscessful API call...

Comment: You can send a CURL request, use fopen, or use file_get_contents. Try Google, or here's a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064980/php-curl-vs-file-get-contents.

Comment: can you please tell me the full code please... I am a beginner.. I tried Google but i am not successful yet!

Comment: Check the link provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way, but need php option allow_url_fopen  to be enabled (it is by default, but somehosting disable it) is to use file_get_contents function so it would be just

```
$result = file_get_contents($url);
```

If that option is anavailale or you need more complicated request I will offer you to use curl extention. It's usually enabled and in your simple case you can use it like

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about `CURL` or `Guzzle`.

I recommend You `Guzzle`.

[Guzzle Github](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

There is some example covers your needs.

Comment: Why Guzzle? There are built in functions for this.

Comment: can you please tell me the full code please... I am a beginner.. I tried Google but i am not successful yet! –