# why file_get_contents('external_url') is not working in cron job? Are there any alternate process?

Tags: php, cron, instagram, file-get-contents, instagram-api

I created a php cron job, to fetch the Instagram feeds. My code is as follows..

```
$homepage = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/XXXXXX/media/recent?access_token=XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXX&count=8", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions)); $json = json_decode($homepage);
```

When I execute this code through web-browser, it was working fine.  But it was not executing from cron job.

I am using cron job command line as follows..

```
cd /home/MY_SITE/public_html/content/insta/ && php index.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

please help me.. Thanks.

Comment: Is your cron executing? first check your cron is running. the code should be run in cron if manually running

Comment: Yes @RakeshSharma , It is working fine.  I tested this with a simple mysql_query (Insert query).

Comment: During cron eventually is another $PATH. Giving full pathnames to your files and to php eventually helps.

Comment: Hi @jogo, Can you please explain in brief. with an example.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also try to change your cron command to this

`php /home/MY_SITE/public_html/content/insta/index.php > /tmp/log`

and check `/tmp/log` file probably there is logged some error

Comment: Thanks @Armen, will try this and let you know.

Comment: hmm that /tmp/ folder is writable for www-data and after first execution php should be able to create it , but yes you can try to create it manually and chmod /tmp/log to 0777, and set cron to be executed every 1 min by adding */1 * * * * and after one minute check /tmp/log file

Comment: I am getting the below code in log file.                                               `Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.43
Content-type: text/html
No input file specified.`

Comment: Seems your instagram link is wrong, but you can try first one again run your index.php with browser with enabled php errors `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and check if that error exists on page or check /var/log/apache2/error.log file for same error and if it present then you have to convert your `file_get_contents` to `curl` request it works more stable as suggested for example here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204586/file-get-contents-and-error-codes

Comment: No @armen, the given link is correct, It is working fine from web-browser.. I also tried curl.. but no luck.. Thanks.