# Handle php errors with is statment

Tags: php

I want an if statment thats checks for specific error from php script 
the error is this

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.google.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\xampp\htdocs\google\index.php on line 196
```

my code

```
if (file_get_contents('http://www.google.com') === false {
   echo 'faild';  
}
```

I want to skip only 404 error

ps: I'm not using my code on google website but I cant write the real url

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You can not check for 404 error with `file_get_contents(), this function will return `true` or `false`. Your best shut is to use an `.htacces` file, set the conditional `ErrorDocument 404     /404.html` end then create the `404.html page which will automatically display if a `404` error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to [add a error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241728/can-i-try-catch-a-warning) and parse the error message to check for the `404 Not Found` or [check the http code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4358138/5878195) before doing your file_get_contents

Comment: just perfect thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can use php curl for fetching the remote page. It allows you to check the http status code. See example 2 on http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php