# Fastest way to ping thousands of websites using PHP

Tags: php, performance

I'm currently pinging URLs using CURL + PHP. But in my script, a request is sent, then it waits until the response comes, then another request, ... If each response takes ~3s to come, in order to ping 10k links it takes more than 8 hours!

Is there a way to send multiple requests at once, like some kind of multi-threading?

Thank you.

Comment: why you want to use php for ping website just use python and enjoy

Comment: I prefer PHP because I can't code with python. But if there's no other solution, I'll have to learn some.

Comment: @Rahul a common name: You make a compelling argument...

Comment: pinging(ICMP echo) is almost instant for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either fork your php process using [`pcntl_fork`](http://php.net/pcntl_fork) or look into curl's built-in multi-threading. https://web.archive.org/web/20091014034235/http://www.ibuildings.co.uk/blog/archives/811-Multithreading-in-PHP-with-CURL.html

Comment: You can also use exec to do PHP multithreading by calling PHP files on the commandline and not waiting for a response. However, this is no good for anything that takes parameters, because you never want to stuff user data into exec.

Comment: Neat, didn't know of that one

Answer (score 4):

USe the `curl_multi_*` functions available in curl. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

You must group the URLs in smaller sets: Adding all 10k links at once is not likely to work. So create a loop around the following code and use a subset of URLS (like 100) in the `$urls` variable.

```
$all = array();
$handle = curl_multi_init();
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $all[$url] = curl_init();
    // Set curl options for $all[$url]
    curl_multi_add_handle($handle, $all[$url]);
}
$running = 0;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($handle, $running;);
} while ($running > 0);
foreach ($all as $url => $curl) {
    $content = curl_multi_getcontent($curl);
    // do something with $content
    curl_multi_remove_handle($handle, $curl);
}
curl_multi_close($handle);
```

Answer (score 4):

First off I would like to point out that this is not a basic task which you can do on any kind of shared hosting provider. I assume you will get banned for sure.

So I assume you are able to compile software(VPS?) and start long running processes in the background(using [php cli](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/php-command-line-1)). I would use a [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/)(I liked [predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis/) as PHP client library very much) to [push](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/RpushCommand) messages on a list. (**P.S: I would prefer to write this in node.js/python(explanation below works for PHP), because I think this task can be coded in these languages pretty fast. I am going to try and write it and post code on github later.**)

**Redis:**

> Redis is an advanced key-value store.
>   It is similar to memcached but the
>   dataset is not volatile, and values
>   can be strings, exactly like in
>   memcached, but also lists, sets, and
>   ordered sets. All this data types can
>   be manipulated with atomic operations
>   to push/pop elements, add/remove
>   elements, perform server side union,
>   intersection, difference between sets,
>   and so forth. Redis supports different
>   kind of sorting abilities.

Then start a couple of worker processes which will [take](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/BlpopCommand)(blocking if none available) messages from the list.

**Blpop:**

> This is where Redis gets really
>   interesting. BLPOP and BRPOP are the
>   blocking equivalents of the LPOP and
>   RPOP commands. If the queue for any of
>   the keys they specify has an item in
>   it, that item will be popped and
>   returned. If it doesn't, the Redis
>   client will block until a key becomes
>   available (or the timeout expires -
>   specify 0 for an unlimited timeout).

Curl is not exactly pinging(ICMP Echo), but I guess some servers could block these requests(security). I would first try to [ping](http://systemnotesorg.blogspot.com/2007/12/ping-multiple-hosts-using-bash-nmap-and.html)(using nmap snippet part) the host, and fail back to curl if ping fails, because pinging is faster then using curl.

**Libcurl:**

> A free client-side URL transfer
>   library, supporting FTP, FTPS, Gopher
>   (protocol), HTTP, HTTPS, SCP, SFTP,
>   TFTP, TELNET, DICT, FILE, LDAP, LDAPS,
>   IMAP, POP3, SMTP and RTSP (the last
>   four—only in versions newer than
>   7.20.0 or 9 February 2010)

**Ping:**

> Ping is a computer network
>   administration utility used to test
>   the reachability of a host on an
>   Internet Protocol (IP) network and to
>   measure the round-trip time for
>   messages sent from the originating
>   host to a destination computer. The
>   name comes from active sonar
>   terminology. Ping operates by sending
>   Internet Control Message Protocol
>   (ICMP) echo request packets to the
>   target host and waiting for an ICMP
>   response.

But then you should do a HEAD request and only retrieve headers to check if host is up. Otherwise you would also be downloading content of url(takes time/cost bandwidth).

**HEAD:**

> The HEAD method is identical to GET
>   except that the server MUST NOT return
>   a message-body in the response. The
>   metainformation contained in the HTTP
>   headers in response to a HEAD request
>   SHOULD be identical to the information
>   sent in response to a GET request.
>   This method can be used for obtaining
>   metainformation about the entity
>   implied by the request without
>   transferring the entity-body itself.
>   This method is often used for testing
>   hypertext links for validity,
>   accessibility, and recent
>   modification.

Then each worker process should use curl_multi. I think [this](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/) link might provide a good implementation of this(minus it does not do head request). to have some sort of concurrency in each process.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't have true multi-thread capabilities.

However, you could always make your CURL requests asynchronously.

This would allow you to fire off batches of pings instead of one at a time.

Reference: [How do I make an asynchronous GET request in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962915/how-do-i-make-an-asynchronous-get-request-in-php)

Edit: Just keep in mind your gonna have to make your PHP wait until all responses come back before terminating.

- Christian

Answer (score 1):

curl has the "multi request" facility which is essentially a way of doing threaded requests. Study the example on this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP exec() function to execute unix commands like wget to accomplish this.

```
exec('wget -O - http://example.com/url/to_ping /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

It's by no means an ideal solution but does get the jobs done and by sending the output to /dev/null and running it in the background you can move onto the next "ping" without having to wait for the response.

Note: Some servers have exec() disabled for security purposes.

Comment: Too bad for the down without a comment about what was bad :/ [StackOverflow Down Vote Privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`system()`](http://php.net/system) and execute the ping script as a new process. Or multiple processes.

You can make a centralized queue with all addresses to ping, then kick of some ping scripts on the task.

Just note:

> If a program is started with this
>   function, in order for it to continue
>   running in the background, the output
>   of the program must be redirected to a
>   file or another output stream. Failing
>   to do so will cause PHP to hang until
>   the execution of the program ends.

Comment: Probably because system() and exec() are considered 'dangerous'.

Comment: `mysql_query` can also be dangerous, but I don't see people down-voting answers with it. `system` is in no way dangerous if you don't inject unescaped user input into the call.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this kind of tasks try out I/O multiplexing strategies. In a nutshell, the idea is that you create a bunch of sockets, feed them to your OS (say, using **epoll** on linux / **kqueue** on FreeBSD) and sleep until an event occurs on some of the sockets. Your OS's kernel can handle hundreds or even thousands of sockets in parallel in a *single* process.

You can not only handle TCP sockets but also deal with timers / file descriptors in a similar fashion in parallel.

Back to PHP, check out something like https://github.com/reactphp/event-loop which exposes a good API and hides lots of low-level details.

Answer (score -1):

Run multiple php processes.

Process 1: pings sites 1-1000

Process 2: pings sites 1001-2001

...