# Asynchronous HTTP request in PHP with delegate

Tags: php, http, asynchronous

how can I make an asynchronous HTTP request in PHP passing a delegate to the function?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can do that in php. The closest thing would be `curl_multi_init()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't really support async callbacks since there are no interrupts in the language.  <strike>Your best of using curl, and then checking back on the request to see if it has finished.</strike> You can also use `fsockopen` and friends to do it on a socket level.

[Check out this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962915/how-do-i-make-an-asynchronous-get-request-in-php/962920#962920) You'll need to tweak it to save the result socket (and process it), but the basic idea is there.