# PHP keeping process alive

Tags: php, process

I am struggling to find a solution to a problem where a user visits to page1.php and this page include another page2.php which takes lot of time (~5 minute) to complete all the computation but the results of the computation doesn't need to be displayed to user. So, its not worth to make the user to wait for its completion.

I am looking for a solution where user should visit page1.php and after some necessary check listing it should display message to the user that his request processing has started. And on the back end page2.php should complete all of its working even if user should have closed window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out this link [How do I make an asynchronous GET request in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962915/how-do-i-make-an-asynchronous-get-request-in-php)
if you would like to get the result displayed on the request page, use file_get_contents

Comment: After firing off GET request what guarantees that the process will remain invoked and complete all the working even when user have closed the page or even browser because it closes the handle immediately?

Comment: you may check out http://us2.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php. Try ignore_user_abort()

Answer (score 0):

Offload the actual computation to a standalone process (a cron job, or a custom daemon) and implement some sort of job queue (e.g., using a database). So your front-end (the PHP website) would add the data to a database table, and then periodically check back on it (e.g. by reading a 'progress' column or something); the processing daemon would look in the table to see if there are any new jobs, and if so, start processing them, updating the table as needed.