# Can I POST from one PHP script to another using phpQuery, or if possible, just plain PHP?

Tags: php, post, web-crawler, phpquery

There are numerous examples of being able to POST a variable from one PHP script to another.

I want the first script to POST to the second script, but to keep the first script still running. The files are crawler.php and links.php. How do I do this?

Comment: This is the first time I've seen a reporter from the Daily Mail write a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry! I wa slightly annoyed that last time I asked a question, 20 people commented saying that it was too hard, or that you couldn't (you can), or that they needed more information than was humanly possible to include.

Comment: Can you desribe exatly what you are trying to do and specifically what  you mean by "post" (ie. a second http request, passing through a socket, etc..)

Comment: @tandu I've seen a solution in a Google search that did that, but it made no sense to me at all.

Comment: `to keep the first script still running` concurrent php programming?)

Comment: @Thomas: can you post the link?

Comment: @prodigitalson a second HTTP request. And what link?
k102, I haven't heard about that, GOOGLE SESSION!

Comment: Two ways that I'd consider: CURL (http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) alternatively output an AJAX request to the browser to run another PHP script.

Comment: @DavidBarker I was trying to keep it all on the server, sorry should have made it more clear!

Comment: @TiesonT. Sorry, I was in a bad mood after my last experience on this site...

Comment: @Thomas Foster Fair enough, just thought it may explain why you weren't getting much in the way of suggestions. Don't have to apologize to me... :)

Comment: Asking such pointless questions you will always have bad experience on this site. To have a good experience, one have to put much more efforts, asking not 2-liner question making very little sense but posting whole problem description in terms that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Use cURL

```
<?php 
// crawler.php
$url = 'localhost/links.php'; // Change me to what ever
$fields = array('foo' => 'bar');

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

See http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

**Edit:**

I just realised you wanted an async call.

In that case, you can look into pcntl fork http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php

Or [How do I make an asynchronous GET request in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962915/how-do-i-make-an-asynchronous-get-request-in-php)

Comment: Does that require for something to be sent back to the original script? (the edit) I just didn't want the first script to stop running after I had sent the request, which is what the examples I saw did. The cURL will work I guess :)