# Send email Asynchronously via PhpMailer

Tags: php, email, asynchronous, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send email which works great. The issue however is that since it sends the email synchronously, the subsequent page load takes a long time.

I am using PhpMailer as shown in this example https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

I wonder if there is a way to make email delivery asynchronous. I researched this and found that sendmail has an option to set DeliveryMode to "background mode" - source http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, 'O DeliveryMode=b');
```

I want to know if something similar can be done in PhpMailer? Has anyone had any success with this?

**EDIT:- (Additional info)** It seems like PhpMailer can be configured to  use sendmail - https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php
Therefore I wonder if this can be somehow leveraged to enable background delivery.

```
/**
 * Which method to use to send mail.
 * Options: "mail", "sendmail", or "smtp".
 * @type string
 */
public $Mailer = 'mail';

/**
 * The path to the sendmail program.
 * @type string
 */
public $Sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
/**
 * Whether mail() uses a fully sendmail-compatible MTA.
 * One which supports sendmail's "-oi -f" options.
 * @type boolean
 */
public $UseSendmailOptions = true;

/**
 * Send messages using $Sendmail.
 * @return void
 */
public function isSendmail()
{
    $ini_sendmail_path = ini_get('sendmail_path');
    if (!stristr($ini_sendmail_path, 'sendmail')) {
        $this->Sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
    } else {
        $this->Sendmail = $ini_sendmail_path;
    }
    $this->Mailer = 'sendmail';
}
```

Also - apparently there is way to set sendmail options via php.ini
http://blog.oneiroi.co.uk/linux/php/php-mail-making-it-not-suck-using-sendmail/

I would prefer to do this as an inline argument to the api call vs php.ini so that isnt a global change. Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wrong approach.

PHPMailer is not a mail server, which is what you're asking it to be. SMTP is a verbose, chatty protocol that's prone to delays and slow throughput, and is absolutely unsuited to sending interactively during a typical web page submission (which is what the question BlackHatSamurai linked to is probably doing). Many get away with doing precisely that, but don't be fooled into thinking it's a good solution, and definitely don't try to implement an MTA yourself.

The gmail example you linked to is using SMTP to a remote server, which will always be slower than submitting locally. If you're submitting via sendmail (or `mail()` - it's basically the same thing) to a local server and it's taking more than about 0.1 sec, you're doing something very wrong. Even SMTP to localhost won't take much longer, and sending to a nearby smarthost is unlikely to be too slow either.

Trying to background things using threads is a massive can of worms that is exactly not the way to go about this - whatever you achieve that way would be terrible compared to a proper mail server. Just don't do it.

The right way to do this is to install a local mail server, and submit your messages to it with PHPMailer. This way is very fast (hundreds of messages per second), and you have to do precisely *nothing* to make it work because that's how PHPMailer works by default.

The mail server will then do what it's supposed to do - queue your message, deal with connection problems, delivery deferrals, bounces and everything else you've not considered.

Comment: Fantastic response. Thanks for the detailed explanation. Much appreciated!! I am somewhat of a noob when it comes to this subject matter - do you have any recommendations on which mail server to choose/install. I am on a shared hosting plan. Not sure if my webhost will allow me to install a custom one.

Comment: Most linux distros use postfix, which I prefer to exim. There are plenty of others though. If your ISP won't let you install one, they probably provide something already, or a nearby smarthost - check their docs, open a support ticket. If they don't, I'd suggest installing a new service provider...

Comment: Thanks @Synchro. I ended up using the default mail server provided by my hosting provider & noticed (with timestamping) that it was taking roughly 2 secs per email. So I called my webhost & they said that since I was on a shared hosting plan, that delay was expected (apparently their mail server sends to a proxy where its queued before sending). Finally I set  "-O DeliveryMode=b" in my php.ini(http://blog.oneiroi.co.uk/linux/php/php-mail-making-it-not-suck-using-sendmail/) which made a HUGE difference. The emails are now sent in background mode & my script returns in **0.16 secs!**

Comment: That's cool. You can probably set that param from inside PHPMailer using `isSendmail()` and setting `Sendmail` to `/usr/sbin/sendmail -O DeliveryMode=b`.

Comment: Yes I agree but I'll have to remember to do it manually when I upgrade to future PhpMailer versions. The better alternative would be to officially change the isSendmail() API to accept options as an argument - isSendmail($options). Something to consider for the next phpMailer  update.

Comment: What? That is what the Sendmail property is for - just set it in your instance, no need to touch the library code.

Comment: Oh I get it now. I misunderstood your earlier point. thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Right. I did a different approach. I save the email to my local database and then i immediately call my php script by shell exec asynchronously which then uses the database and sent the email. No delay, but a bit of work...

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342214/send-asynchronous-email-with-phpmailer) `phpMailer` doesn't support this type of call. You would have to write your own threaded class in order to do make an async call. See [pThreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) and the [Thread](http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php) class. One other solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962915/how-do-i-make-an-asynchronous-get-request-in-php).

Comment: Thanks for your response and the links. I wonder if thats completely accurate (upto date) because phpMailer seems to allow sendmail as a delivery mechanism. I will edit my question and add this info to it.

Comment: @rogerb, regardless  you'd have to rewrite the Sendmail class to use an async thread.

Comment: What about using a smarthost?