# Execute function only once to save time

Tags: javascript, php, function, email, phpmailer

I have a function for email, please find the code below:

```
function sendEmail($userName, $password, $sendTo, $sendToName, $subject, $body, $mailSent){

        $mail             = new PHPMailer();
        // $body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

        $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
        --------
        --------
        --------

        $mail->SetFrom($userName, 'Rajendra Arora');

        $mail->AddReplyTo($userName,"Rajendra Arora");

        $mail->Subject    = $subject;

        $mail->Body    = $body; // optional, comment out and test
    }
```

This email function has an attachment with long file size but whenever this email function is called by using `sendEmail();`. It is executed everytime and takes much time as it has to go through the whole execution program with primarily upload.

Is there any way to execute this `sendEmail()`function only for once time. So that we could call it simply once and saves time from preventing to upload?

Comment: Memoization is valid only for function that have no side effects. The function you're talking about probably sends mail, but it's unclear from description.

Comment: What I mean to say, can we execute this whole `sendEmail()` function only for once time. so that whenever next time we call `sendEmail()` anywhere, It has not to go through the whole `sendEmail()` function and simply it implies with already execution with upload file changes.

Comment: File upload takes time because SMTP needs to upload the file every time you send a letter. Everything else takes almost no time.

Comment: Exactly, Thanks anyway .. @jens108 has already pointed me some suggestion. :)

Comment: Beware that all recipients will know emails of each other then.

Comment: Really? ??? Is there any other way suggest for this job process?

Comment: a) Make the size of attachments smaller; b) Send emails in several parallel threads, better in a language that supports parallel/asynchronous programming unlike PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email Asynchronously via PhpMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743260/send-email-asynchronously-via-phpmailer)

Answer (score 0):

If your emails have the same contents, you can send the same mail to multiple users: you just need to call the AddAddress method once for every recipient. Like so:

```
$mail->AddAddress('person1@domain.com', 'Person One');
$mail->AddAddress('person2@domain.com', 'Person Two');
```