# Unable to send array of objects via POST over socket connection in php

Tags: php, php-socket

I am totally new to php. I had 2 pages let A.php and B.php want to run Page B while I am at Page A.For that I had created a Socket Connection and  able to run The Page B but problem is that when I send an array of objects to page B.page A send only the First object listed in the array and other values of the array were nothing 
here is my some code
in A.php

```
$arr = array("message" => $pushData,
  "messageType" => $messageType,
  "displayGroupID" => $displayGroupID,
  "db"=>$db);
$fp1 = $this->JobStartAsync('localhost', 'B.php', $arr);
$r1 = $this->JobPollAsync($fp1);

function JobStartAsync($server, $url, $data, $port=80,$conn_timeout=10, $rw_timeout=86400)
{
    $errno = '';
    $errstr = '';
    $data = http_build_query($data);

    set_time_limit(0);

    $fp = fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr, $conn_timeout);

    if (!$fp)
    {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
        return false;
    }

    $out = "POST $url HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: $server\r\n";
    $out .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $out .= "Content-length: ". strlen($data) ."\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    $out .= "$data";
    stream_set_blocking($fp, false);
    stream_set_timeout($fp, $rw_timeout);
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    //fwrite($fp, $data);
    return $fp;
}

function JobPollAsync(&$fp)
{
    if ($fp === false)
        return false;

    if (feof($fp))
    {
        fclose($fp);
        $fp = false;
        return false;
    }

    return fread($fp, 10000);
}
```

IN B.php

```
fileWrite ($_POST['displayGroupID'],$_POST['message'],$_POST['messageType']);
```

it get only "message" as it is listed as 1st element in array

Comment: If you want someone to spend time on your question and help you out, you should rather spend more time improving your question. And may be add some sample code that you have been working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code). This is what you need and everyone else uses.

```
ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

For async variation take a look at a similar question answered before - [How do I make an asynchronous GET request in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962915/how-do-i-make-an-asynchronous-get-request-in-php)