# PHP threading call to a php function asynchronously

Tags: php

What I'm looking to do is load in some data from a database or from memcache asynchronously.

I know, I know.  "PHP doesn't support threading".

But what about register_tick_function?  Isn't that indeed threading?

Has anyone done any kind of predictive preload or really any background processing utilizing register_tick_function?

Comment: No, everything _halts_ on a tick function. `gearman` is a nice way to offload some work to another process. Or a bit of forking can be done it you're not using php in a webserver but from the command line.

Comment: php does support threading, but i don't think you need that for your particular problem

Comment: @Wrikken, I understand that everything else halts on tick.  But think of threading on a single processor, single threaded machine.  That's how they implement threading.

Comment: @Ibu, it does? Native threading? Do you have any more information on this?

Comment: @Wrikken, thanks for the note on gearman.  Very interesting, I'm not sure it'll work here because I need to load data into the memory available to the user that's run the page.  But very interesting for other purposes.

Comment: No, PHP does not support threading. Forking, yes, native threading, no. I assume Ibu confuses it with something else... And yeah, pseudo threading like that can be attempted that way with ticks, but does not scale well at all of course.

Comment: doesn't scale well in terms of running much code that way?  Would you say that a database query or a memcache call would be too much?

Comment: ... and for gearman, if you need _more_ then function arguments can handle, shared memory and/or memcached can be your friends (although memcached is designed to drop data, so keep in mind that should not cause fatal errors...).

Comment: Does not scale well = does not use the available hardware to it's fullest as I see it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21026/discussion-between-beachhouse-and-wrikken)

Comment: Basically closing this.  There is NO ADVANTAGE to using the tick function.  Any delay in the tick function will delay code execution everywhere.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

http://php.net/pthreads

http://docs.php.net/Thread

PHP certainly can support threading. Loading data from a SQL/NoSQL database in parallel is definitely a possibility. See the PHP manual, examples found in github and pecl packages.

Please note, the documentation did state that this is part of the core, this is ( my ) human error. You must install pthreads with a thread-safe version of php, it can be installed from pecl ( windows incuded, dlls @ http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads ). Apologies.

Comment: Am not sure if this download links leads to the latest versions

Comment: I know this is old but I think it's worth noting that pthreads at this time (3.1.6) only supports php 7.2+ so you'll need to build php with zts enabled form a version of php greater than or equal to 7.2

Comment: Apparently both of those URLs php.net/pthreads and docs.php.net/Thread say that they (pthreads) are no longer maintained and to use parallel instead (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.parallel.php), except the comments on the bottom of this answer make it sound like parallel is also a dead end -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15501449/3470632