# PHP run parallel class instances

Tags: php

```
$a=new FileProcessing($path1);
$b=new FileProcessing($path2); 
$a->doProcessFile();
$b->doProcessFile();
```

this code run `doProcessFile()` for `$a` then run `doProcessFile()` for `$b` in **sequential order**.
I want run `doProcessFile()` for `$a` in **parallel** with `doProcessFile()` for `$b` so I can process different file in **parralel**.
I can do that in PHP ?

As I can see, PHP process script in sequential order only. Now I wonder if I can run multiple instances of the same script in parralel ,the difference between running scripts is  a parameter I pass when I call each script. for example : `php myscript.php [path1]` then I call this script a second time with different parameter.

Comment: No. PHP is not a multi-threaded language. Your only recourse is to `exec()` or otherwise spawn two SEPARATE instances of php, each doing their separate path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236296/asynchronous-function-call-in-php

Comment: Like @MarcB mentioned PHP is not multi-threaded. Besides using exec you could also look into solutions like beanstalkD http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/

Comment: @tlenss - php isn't multithreaded? www.php.net/Thread disagrees with you :/

Comment: @N.B.pthreads is not part of the core. So the answer remains. However it's a viable option here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pcntl_fork`](http://php.net/manual/function.pcntl-fork.php), but only when running PHP from command line instead of as a web server.

Alternately, you can use [gearman](http://www.php.net/manual/intro.gearman.php).

Answer (score 0):

Never tried that myself but in theory should be possible:

1. Convert your `doProcessingFile` method to a standalone PHP script `process_file.php` that takes file to process as input.
2. Put the files for processing to a folder created for that sole purpose
3. Create a shell script `paralellizer` that will list the folder with files to process and send the files for parallel processing (note that it accepts number of files to process as arg - this bit could maybe be done nicer as a part of oneliner below):

   ```
    #!/bin/bash

    ls special_folder | xargs -P $1 -n 1 php process_file.php
   ```
4. Call `parallelizer` from php and make sure process_file returns processing result status :

   ```
    $files_to_process = Array($path1, $path2); 
    exec('parallelizer '.count($files_to_process), $output);
    // check output
    // access processed files
   ```

disclaimer: just a rough ugly sketch of idea. I'm sure it can be improved

Answer (score 0):

make 2 files

1. processor.php

```
<?php
if($arc < 1) user_error('needs a argument');
$a=new FileProcessing($argv[1]);
$a->doProcessFile();
```

2. caller.php

```
<?php
function process($path,$name){
  $a = array();
  $descriptorspec = array(
    1 => array("file", "/tmp/$name-output.txt", "a"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
    2 => array("file", "/tmp/$name-error.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
  );
  return proc_open(PHP_BINARY.' processor.php '.escapeshellarg($path), $descriptorspec, $a);
}
$proc1 = process($path1,'path1');
$proc2 = process($path2,'path2');
//now wait for them to complete
if(proc_close($proc1))user_error('proc1 returned non 0');
if(proc_close($proc2))user_error('proc2 returned non 0');
echo 'All done!!';
```

be sure to read the documentation of [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) to for more information, also note that you need to include the class(and anything it needs) in the processor because its a new php environment