# How to use php function asynchronously

Tags: php, asynchronous

I have a php function and i want it to work asynchronously.

```
function my_function1(){
//some code
my_async_func();

}

function my_async_func(){
// doing background task

}
```

any help is most welcome

i have visited [PHP threading call to a php function asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846192/php-threading-call-to-a-php-function-asynchronously)

but i don't want to use php threading

Comment: Then go for it! What is your problem/question?!

Comment: _"but i don't want to use php threading"_ Then you are probably SOL.

Comment: PHP has no support for asynchronous stuff, OTHER than using threads. So if you don't want to use threads, then you can't really do async calls.

Comment: don't know how to do with out php threading

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Function Call in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236296/asynchronous-function-call-in-php)

Comment: #DanMan I don't want to use Php thread the solution you have provided i pointed it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, php is not meant to work that way.

You can run a separate background process, which checks database for jobs to be done and does them. But that is not true async. It's just a background worker.