# Execute return then call another function in PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, asynchronous, fork

I have a function to execute some database input then send notification to a user, the problem is when i execute the send notification to a user is taking some time, i need this process to run in background but i don't know how to do it, here is my code:

```
public function execute(){
 $data = $this->insertToDatabase();
 $this->sendNotification($data); //this function takes a lot of time
 return $data;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Function Call in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236296/asynchronous-function-call-in-php)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel i used try catch & finally , but it still takes a lot of time

Comment: @TinyDancer `try catch` doesn't make something async. I think you've misunderstood the purpose of `try catch`.

Comment: @Script47 can i use fork for this case?