# How do I monitor changes in a database from unity without flooding the NIC

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine, webrequest

I have a web server which contains a sql database. There are two "users" to this server/database. One is the actual user where they will submit changes through a UnityWebRequest using HTTP:Post. This will make changes to the database.

I have another system that is also in Unity, that needs to be notified, or somehow monitor for whenever a change is made to a specific table in a database. I don't know how to monitor the table for changes without constantly making select calls to the database.

What I've tried

I have a unity function which calls the webserver through HTTP:Post. The webserver goes into an infinite while loop making calls to the database something like

```
$variable = $_REQUEST['variable_to_monitor'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT variable_to_monitor FROM table_name;")
while(true){
    $stmt->execute();
    results = $stmt->fetchAll()[0];
    if ($variable != results['variable_to_monitor']){
        die(results['variable_to_monitor']);
    }
}
```

This holds up the webserver and is making too many calls to the database.

I would like for Unity to be able to make a single call to a web server giving it a given state, the web server will compare said state to database until the database changes, then once the db changes respond to unity with the updated state. I want to be able to do this without making a million SELECT calls to a database per second.

Unity Code

```
    void Update()
    {
        if(hasResponse)
        {
            hasResponse = false;
            StartCoroutine(SendRequest());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SendRequest(WWWForm form = null, Action<string> callback = null)
    {
        if(null == form) form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("request", "monitor_variable");
        form.AddField("variable_to_monitor", this.variable_to_monitor);

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log("Network Error");
        }
        else if (www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log("Http Error");
        }
        else
        {
            if(null == callback)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!www.downloadHandler.text.Contains("New Request Started"))
                {
                    hasResponse = true;
                    callback(www.downloadHandler.text);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you make the call in Unity?

Comment: using UnityWebRequest.Post();

Comment: yes I read that in the question but I ment how exactly? (code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Function Call in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236296/asynchronous-function-call-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can and always should wait in Unity for the [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) to finish! You should allways use e.g. a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

And than you can as well e.g. add a time offset so you don't make a new request right ahead but maybe wait a few seconds.

I personally would also add callbacks for the response which makes it way more flexible and reusable e.g.

```
public void MakeRepeatedRequests(string url, float timeOffset, Action<string> successCallback, Action<string> errorCallback)
{
    StartCoroutine(RepeatedRequestRoutine(url, timeOffset, successCallback, errorCallback);
}

private IEnumerator RepeatedRequestRoutine(string url, float timeOffset, Action<string> successCallback, Action<string> errorCallback)
{
    // No worries this still looks like a while loop (well it is ^^)
    // but the yield makes sure it doesn't block Unity's UI thread
    while(true)
    {
        // Configure your request
        var request = UnityWebRequest.Post(url);

        // Make the request and wait until the it has finished (has a response or timeout)
        // a yield kind of tells this routine to leave, let Unity render this frame
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if(request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError) 
        {
            errorCallback?.Invoke(request.error);
        }
        else 
        {
            successCallback?.Invoke(request.downloadHandler.text);
        }

        // Now wait for the timeOffset
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeOffset);
    }
}
```

---

Now you can call it e.g. for waiting 2 seconds after the last request **finished**

```
// ...

    MakeRepeatedRequests ("http://example.com", 2.0f, OnSuccess, OnError);

// ...

private void OnSuccess(string success)
{
    Debug.LogFormat(this, "Nice it worked! Server said:/"{0}/"", success);

    // Do something e.g. using success
}

private void OnError(string error)
{
    Debug.LogFormat(this, "Oh no, request failed with \"{0}\"", error);
}
```

or also do the same thing using lambda expressions

```
MakeRepeatedRequests ("http://example.com", 2.0f, 

    success =>
    {
        Debug.LogFormat(this, "Nice it worked! Server said:/"{0}/"", success);

        // Do something e.g. using success
    }, 

    error =>
    {
        Debug.LogFormat(this, "Oh no, request failed with \"{0}\"", error);

        // Do something else
    });
```

---

Even if you don't want the `timeOffset` this at least waits for every request to finish before starting the next one so your server only has to make one DB query and either return a success or an error.

In your case I would respond with a success (200) anyway (because error should be sent only if the server really had an error) but either send an empty `string` or some predefined one you can check for in Unity (something like e.g. `"!NO_CHANGE!"`).

so on the server side without a loop something like e.g.

```
results = "SELECT * FROM table_name;"
if ($_REQUEST['variable_name'] != results['variable_name']){
    echo results['variable_name'];
} else {
    echo "!NO_CHANGE!";
}
```

than you could later in Unity check it

```
if(string.Equals(success, "!NO_CHANGE!")) return;
```

Comment: Sorry if my question isn't clear enough, my problem isn't with unity. What I'm trying to do is have unity send a webrequest (which I have implemented, and you provided) and have the web server respond say 5 minutes later, or whenever a change has been made in a db. I don't want to have unity send a request every half second or so, but once every 5 minutes, or whenever it gets a response. I have code for that, but my issue is that I don't know how to write a php script that will wait to respond until a db has been changes. Right now I have the php script go into the while loop in my question

Comment: oh but than why the `Unity3d` tag if this is actually only about `php`? Note that I'm pretty sure you can not wait until you get a response and then answer to Unity ... you will allways have to make repeated calls from the Unity side and either respond with nothing or respond with the changes. => You have to request repeatedly anyway so what's the problem using the above approach?

Comment: I put the unity tag because using UnityWebRequest has different options than if it were a web browser making post calls. I'm pretty sure if I was using a web browser I could use ajax or something similar - though I've never used ajax so I don't exactly know

Comment: As I said already I would not make the server wait at all .. I would make Unity make a request in certain intervals and if there was a change meanwhile send it, otherwise respond with a "NO_Change" so Unity knows the server still works but there where no change. There doesn't seem to be something like in JavaScript where you can keep the connection for minutes if you want to.. but as already said I wouldn't make the waiting on the server at all.