# PHP asinchronous execution

Tags: php, apache, asynchronous, webserver

I made a php script to load some data to a serial device, this operation take some seconds (10/15). This is not a problem for the requester, the http request take a while to come back like all heavy pages.

My problem is that this script hold all other requests to that Apache/Php web server.

**Is this any way to do something in php asynchonously or to configure php (or apache) to manage it not queuing all other requests?**
Now my apache and php configuration is the standard production configuration.

Comment: What is the information? Are you reading or writing from the device? Would it be possibly to write a small daemon that continually reads from the device, and publishes it somewhere that the PHP script could quickly read the (most recent) result from?

Comment: Yes, can be, but I would like to know if there is some way to write a "thread job" in php to run asyncronously or at least to not hold all other request to that server.

Comment: Something is wrong with your webserver (not PHP) configuration if one long page request is blocking all others.

Comment: Agree with @JonathonReinhart , posted answer to your question still however.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, PHP wasn't made for Asynchronism.. If you want a Async solution, you should maybe take a look at NodeJS.

However, there are quite a number of PHP libraries, that allow you to mimic this sort of behaviour, however, I can't promise what kind of overhead you will experience, or how reliable these libraries are.

To answer your question more directly: You can't configure Apache and PHP to handle (or mimic) it's request Asynchronously. You will need to do it programatically.

Article one (Threading, this is not Async):
[PHP threading call to a php function asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846192/php-threading-call-to-a-php-function-asynchronously)

Article Two (Segment IO): https://segment.io/blog/how-to-make-async-requests-in-php/

And an example Lib (React PHP): http://reactphp.org/

You're heading down a dark path my friend. PHP was not made for this. One of the many reasons why PHP is dying.