# Call function and continue

Tags: php

Is there a way in PHP to call a function within a script and then continue through the rest of the script without waiting for that function to finish?

For example, if I have a script like this:

```
<?php

    ... some code ...

    getImage($value);

    ... some code ...

?>
```

`getImage()` is a function that takes, on average, 5 seconds to complete. Is there a way to call `getImage()` and continue through the rest of the script without having to wait for a response so that the user doesn't have to wait as long?

Thanks.

Comment: and what do you do with the result of the function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP threading call to a php function asynchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846192/php-threading-call-to-a-php-function-asynchronously)

Comment: @Sebas - A function isn't obliged to return any result, and even if it does, it's not uncommon to ignore it. (When did you last do anything with the return value from the sort() function?)

Comment: @Sebas Nothing. The function does its own thing.

Comment: @MarkBaker, really??!