# Asynchronous Method Call In PHP

Tags: php

I have the following dilemma, I have a SOAP API, need to optimise a method:

```
public function myMethodForOptimisation(array $options) {
    //doing some stuff

    $this->requestsAnUltraSlowTimeConsumingMethod();

    return $someData;
}
```

I do not really need to wait for the finalisation of the `$this->requestsAnUltraSlowTimeConsumingMethod()` i just asynchronously want to say to this method to do stuff and `return` the result to customer.

Need to transform it in something like:

```
public function myMethodForOptimisation(array $options) {
    //doing some stuff

    async_method_call($this->requestsAnUltraSlowTimeConsumingMethod());

    return $someData;
}
```

*Is there an  async_method_call() in PHP ?*

Comment: Threads or fork a cURL request. Either way you need a way of notifying your main application that the resource is available at some point.

Comment: But be aware that it will act different on different operating systems as well as on different webserver configuration. Some methods may not work at all.

Comment: Where does `$someData` come from? Do you want to return something from your async call?

Comment: `$someData` is calculated before the `$this->slowMethod()`,
I proposed to my client to divide this methode in 2, and make 2 request one for the first method and the second for the the other method, but it told me to find a solution only in backoffice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot execute a method asynchronously. But you could return the data to the client, close the connection, and execute your time consuming method once you disconnected.

[This answer goes in details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/close-a-connection-early)

Another solution to execute php code asynchronously is forking a new process with pclose(popen()).

Or for a really advanced solution you could look into the threading module of PHP.

Comment: Hmm i will test that but i guess i will have to play to integrate it in soap.

Answer (score 1):

You may use threads: [PHP threading call to a php function asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846192/php-threading-call-to-a-php-function-asynchronously)

This is quite only way to do so. there is several ways of using them, so choice the best/easiest for you.

Im using this normally: http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

Comment: Thought about it but it requires to compilate the PHP in specific way, `pthreads requires a build of PHP with ZTS (Zend Thread Safety)` do not have the luxury to do that.

Comment: Then you may use DB. Add the data you want to table (id, data, request,anything, flag) . Then set cronjob. If flag is set to `not done`, then in cron job finish the job and set the flag to `done`. This maybe isnt async, but it moves the semi-workthred from the user request to server side.   And then, you may add some easy ajax PINGs with the `delayed` request id, so user can check whenever its finished and receive it.