# Delay due to email send PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

First of all, I would like to thank StackOVerflow and its users for helping me solve a number of technical problems. I created this account today since I could not see similar problem being addressed.

**The problem** - I am stuck with a problem with sending emails in PHP CodeIgniter. The function $this->email->send() is taking around 3-4 seconds each time to execute.

We have a social platform where users come and post things. Every time the user uploads a new update we want to send an email to him/her.
The problem is the send email function takes around 3-4 seconds and we would love to bring it down under 1 second.

IS there any way wherein we can execute the send email process in parallel ? Say a python code which runs continuously to fetch new updates and send emails to those users. Any better method than that ?

Technology stack - PHP CI, MySQL, Apache, Windows

This is the email code that gets called on every new update -

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 587,
        'smtp_user' => 'mailid@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'password',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'utf-8',
        'smtp_crypto' => "tls"
        );

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->from('mailid@gmail.com', 'Support');
$this->email->to($this->session->userdata['email']);
$this->email->subject('You have posted a new update');
$this->email->message('Please login to check your new update. Do not reply to this email. For any issues reach out to email@emailid.com');

if (!$this->email->send())
{
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
else
{
    echo true;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Well that would be great, if you find the answer let us know. 

But I think that may be a good waiting time, even when you send emails from either hotmail or gmail i think i takes longer than 1 minute.

Comment: I would suggest you to use asynchronous functions to send the email. This will help you to complete your logic faster and give quick response. For more information you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846192/php-threading-call-to-a-php-function-asynchronously

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Will try the async methods.

Comment: How is the sending function working? 
When user update status in the same function it emails them? Like this way or you check if any new status later?

Comment: Yes. When user hits post, a function will be called. This function will insert into the database and then send the email. After wards on the success of this action, an ajax function is called to refresh the posts so that user sees the latest post.

Comment: Then this is not the problem of sending. Your other function is making it slower. 
If i could see the exact code, i could understand

Comment: $clean = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post(NULL, TRUE));
$id = $this->update_model->insertUpdate($clean); I execute these two lines before sending the code. If I remove the email block this executes in less than 300ms. If i use the email block it takes ~4 secs

Comment: You may also consider a job queue (such as [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/)) and a (or later on multiple) worker process, that grabs the queued emails and sends them. This can help dealing with error scenarios (email server was not available), you can see what's in the queue, cancel jobs etc.

Comment: It instantly insert into your database or taking some seconds? And user are getting mail after 3-4 secs ?

Comment: Thanks. I don't think the problem is queued emails. Just for sending one email too it takes ~4 secs. I guess the problem is making the smtp connection. That is taking time. If there is any way I can put that in background then I guess that should solve the problem.

Comment: @Imran  It instantly inserts in the database. Users receive the email instantly. The only delay is making the connection and sending the email. Once the action is performed I receive the email immediately.

Comment: Got your problem

Answer (score 1):

It's my suggestion to store the emails in a database and send the emails using a cron job.
The uploading user should not wait to send emails one at a time .

If you need code for a `cron` job or an `smtp mailer`, add a comment to this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only problem with this approach is that I would need to continuously ping the database to check if there are any updates. That might make my database slower. Also, there is a possibility of deadlocks if number of users do updates simultaneously.

Comment: retrieve email  that not sent and set limit 10 , and set crone job time 30 sec .

Comment: @user8625111 its working fine in my project. and delete emails that sent

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your solution. Suppose user A has updated his status as 'test update'. Then should i Store that in a table email_params with column 'to' as userA_email and column 'body' as 'test update'. Now do you suggest that I run a cron or python code that will fetch from this table and send email and then delete the entry ?

Comment: @user8625111  ya its like that and if you attaching some file then save somewhere and better to run seperate cron to delete email , one in a day at some point of time

Comment: @user8625111  sure

Answer (score 1):

If your function is working faster but email sending is slower, it must be problem for your smtp connection. Either your server is not much faster to connect SMTP quickly or the SMTP you are using bit slower to response. 
In that case, try with a gmail SMTP and see the result.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using gmail smtp server with following in my config variable. 'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
 'smtp_port' => 587,

Comment: give a try with your server smtp and see the result.

Comment: Additionally: how much ram you are using in your server?

Comment: its EC2 micro instance with 1 GB ram