# How to send a GET request with cookies and do not wait for response using PHP

Tags: php, cookies, get, request

I want to send some info to a server using cookie for authentication:

```
http://exampleserver.com/get?parm1=val1&parm2=val2&parm3=val3
```

with

```
cookie1=asd123;cookie2=enc%19
```

I want only to send the request and do not wait for the response. I only need server to register the data, as  depending on amount of the data sent, tge wait for the response from client side could become too high, and so I want it to be fast.

I know `PHP` is blocking, but is is possible to do this in some way?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to obtain is like an asynchronous call to the server, which in PHP can be done using "threading", the quotes are here because is not properly threading what is possible in PHP, but almost.

You can find here the answer to your question
[PHP threading call to a php function asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846192/php-threading-call-to-a-php-function-asynchronously)

Comment: I am not sure I am allowed to recompile PHP which on my client server host is installed with zts disabled, so I can not use pthreads.