# Run asynchronous code in laravel controller

Tags: laravel

Is there any way to run mutiple independent function asynchronously in request controller without putting it in queue?

```
public function exampleFunction(Request $request){

    // These are independent functions
    $one = $this->oneFunction();
    $two = $this->anotherFunction();
    $three = $this->differentFunction();

    return response()->json([
        'one'=>$one,
        'two'=> $two,
        'three'=>$three
    ]);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846192/php-threading-call-to-a-php-function-asynchronously

Comment: Well, solution for long running task is simply using queue + cache (in your example). Not possible via queues you need to leverage [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) I bet there are packages that simplify / abstract the API. Good luck and forge some nerves of steel along the way. Also you could use JavaScript to call 3 endpoints and join the results in the JS.