# How can do php asynchronous? It is possible for using pthreads

Tags: php, pthreads

I am newbie in php. i want to run program in asynchronous. I know php is a synchronise language. but my project needs asynchronous. some one says using pthreads it's possible but i don't know how to do that. so please any one can let me know how to use pthreads or any other way to use php asynchronous.

Comment: related, if not a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846192/php-threading-call-to-a-php-function-asynchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start an asynchronous command line php script.

using exec() function.

Example

```
exec(“php asyn.php”.” > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &“);
```