# Async file_put_contents/file_get_contents?

Tags: php, asynchronous, curl, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

Is there a way to download file asynchronously with php?

Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962915/how-do-i-make-an-asynchronous-get-request-in-php) but seem like it's not possible to download file using this method

The problem is that I'm need to download file from API but it took a while to download all images and URL isn't available after call.

Thank you

Comment: Did you look at the Guzzle library which implements the A+ promise to download multiple contents in parallel ?

Comment: @GuillaumeSTLR I didn't know this library but thanks it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @GuillaumeSTLR I managed to do it with [Guzzle Library](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

To make it work. All you have to do is:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$client->getAsync($url, [ 'sink' => $file ]);
```

Comment: You will have to use the `getAsync` method rather than `get`;-)
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#async-requests