# How can I check if an Image exists at http://someurl/myimage.jpg in C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, url

How can I check if an Image exists at http://someurl/myimage.jpg in C#/ASP.NET
It seems like there ought to be a method to check for this -- but I cannot find one.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363925/check-whether-image-exists-on-remote-url), but it doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This code should work:

```
private static bool UrlExists(string url)
{
    try
    {
        new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(url);
        return true;
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException e)
    {
        if (((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            return false;
        else
            throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: This method (DownloadData) can be used to download the image and save it to my server? and if the url doesn't exists show the user an alert that the file can not be downloaded?
Another method from WebClient is DowloadDataAsync, which one is better?

Answer (score 12):

You could try using [`System.Net.WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) to send a 'HEAD" request to that to the url and check the response to see if the file exists - this should do the job without atually trying to download it.

Comment: If the goal is to check for existence only, this is better than System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile. If the goal is to check for existence and then download, this is slightly worse, as it will results in two separate HTTP requests.

Comment: Also, I know of at least two different public web servers that respond with 403 to a HEAD request, while still return 200 for a GET request for the same resource. Not that I condone such behavior; just something to keep in mind. :-)

Answer (score 2):

string fileextension = Path.GetExtension(filename);

```
if (fileextension.ToLower() == ".png" || fileextension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileextension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || fileextension.ToLower() == ".gif" || fileextension.ToLower() == ".bmp"){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://authors.aspalliance.com/brettb/FileAndFolderCheckers.asp) or [this](http://forums.devshed.com/asp-programming-51/how-to-see-if-an-image-file-exists-47863.html) might help. I don't think there's a direct command for images, but you could try using the FileExist method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx) function to try to load the image from the URL and see if you get an error.  (Most likely a 404 Not Found error)

Its about the only way to do it from a URL.  The System.IO namespace and all the functions in there are intended for files on a local machine or a network, so they would be useless to you in this situation.