# Facebook Image URL is invalid (Graph API)

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a Facebook game. In that the 10 opponent picture is displayed. I had saved these profile images in the database once the user had registered.

I am using PHP to echo the image, but the problem is some pictures are being displayed and others are giving me a `‘404’` / `‘400’` or `‘Invalid URL ‘` not found error.
Example: ( These images earlier used to be displayed but not anymore)

```
http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/522851_116822898455075_142765921_q.jpg
https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/199347_134645999940053_5814468_q.jpg.
```

1. How can I fix this problem? Or find some alternative so that the
   broken link of these images is not displayed.
2. I am having the user ID
       of these users, Can I somehow generate new picture if these picture links

   are detected as broken?
3. Is it advisable to hotlink the Picture URLs ? I don't want this
   problem to occur again?

I would appreciate if some one could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this url to fetch profile images of any user using his/her FB user id's

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<fb USER ID>/picture?type=large
```

Comment: Ah okay :) Then what exactly is the issue. I can make out this only from your question, assuming that you are storing image url in your db. As, if you store the whole image then you don't really need a fb url to display the images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363925/check-whether-image-exists-on-remote-url   ....... or do u have this issue

Comment: @charsee- The link that you gave is a dynamic one. When you access this link you will be redirected to a link to a jpeg (it gets converted to a link that I gave above) I have saved these JPEG links in the Database. Earlier all of these links were working , but now some of them have stopped working.

Comment: I dodnt know why are they not working for all the images? May be facebook have changed the image location ( but in this case all running application should have faced this problem ). So I don't know what is wrong.