# Getting default user picture drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal-6

I have a Facebook-style chat on my drupal website, however the script was lacking user picture integration. I managed to get user pictures, but if the user didn't set picture and is using a default picture I'm getting a broken image and a `404 not found` in the logs. I've tried to fetch `gravatar` for users without a picture set, but couldn't make it work.

```
/**
 * This function returns the URL of the avatar of the specified user ID.
 *
 * @param userid the user ID of the user
 * @param image if the image includes more than just a user ID, this param is passed
 * in from the avatar row in the buddylist and get user details functions.
 * @return the link of the user ID's profile
 */
 function get_avatar($image, $user_id, $account) {
   return "http://mypage.com/files/pictures/picture-" . ($user_id) . ".jpg";
   if (empty($account->picture)) {
         return "http://www.gravatar.com/avfatar/" . md5($image) . "?d=identicon";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you return your image immediately, regardless of whether it's there:

```
 function get_avatar($image, $user_id, $account) 
 {
   //THE NEXT LINE RETURNS FROM THE FUNCTION REGARDLESS
   return "http://mypage.com/files/pictures/picture-" . ($user_id) . ".jpg";

   //THIS CODE NEVER RUNS
   if (empty($account->picture)) {
     return "http://www.gravatar.com/avfatar/" . md5($image) . "?d=identicon";
   }
 }
```

What you need to do is the following:

```
 function get_avatar($image, $user_id, $account) 
 {
   $imgurl ="http://mypage.com/files/pictures/picture-" . ($user_id) . ".jpg";

   if (!is_imgurl_good($imgurl)) {
     $imgurl = "http://www.gravatar.com/avfatar/" . md5($image) . "?d=identicon";
   }
   return $imgurl;
 }
```

In the above, you will have to write a function, `is_imgurl_good` that returns a `boolean` indicating whether the image is good. `true` if it is and `false` if not. There are many ways to go about writing that function which is beyond the scope of this question, but you can test the approach with this:

```
function is_imgurl_good($imgurl) {
  return false;//Check that if this returns false the previous function works
  //return true; //Comment out the first line and uncomment this one to show the reverse case.
  //put your actual code here to decide whether $imgurl is a valid image.
}
```

Comment: With this no pictures appear at all. Not sure what to do with the function is_imgurl_good I'm not that advanced coder You see.

Comment: If you implement the above and have `is_imgurl_good` return `true` instead of `false`, does your image show?

Comment: Then the user pics show but the gravatar for those who didn't set up profile pic does not.

Comment: Nor will it until you decide whether the user pic is good or bad. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363925/check-whether-image-exists-on-remote-url Implementing that in `is_imagurl_good` will solve your problem.

Comment: I tried this:

`function is_imgurl_good($imgurl) {
if (@getimagesize($imgurl))
  return true;//Check that if this returns false the previous function works
  //return false; //Comment out the first line and uncomment this one to show the reverse case.
  
}`


but it doesn't works