# How to check image corrupt or not in php?

Tags: php

How to check image corrupt or not using url in php.Is it possible to check in php? I need to check using image url check image corrupt or not.

Comment: Just display image .. then you will see. Dont think PHP is right for this.

Comment: what is it mean by corrupt?

Comment: image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Comment: you can check the size of image corrupt image will return none size

Comment: your file is fine, it's not a corrupt file, url opens your jpg file

Comment: But it's showing error like  cannot be displayed because it contains error na?

Answer (score 6):

Use `getimagesize()` it will return `FALSE` if file corrupt otherwise if file is ok then it will return array containing file info like `mime, height and width etc`, try below example

```
<?php
  $fileName = 'image/corruptsample.jpg'; //filepath
  if(getimagesize($fileName) === false){
    echo "file is corrupted";
  }
  else{
    echo "file is ok";
  }
```

Comment: Only using getimagesize will only detect a subset of curruption types. Most of the common cases of corruption will **not** be detected.

Answer (score 2):

If instead you are looking for a PHP solution instead of a javascript solution (which the potential duplicates do not provide), you can use GD's [getimagesize()](http://php.net/getimagesize) in PHP and see what it returns. It will return false and throw an error when the provided image format is not valid.

**Otherwise You can try that way and get corrupted image**

```
<?php
  $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  if ($ext === 'jpg') {
    $ext = 'jpeg';
  }
  $function = 'imagecreatefrom' . $ext;
  if (function_exists($function) && @$function($image_file) === FALSE) {
    echo 'bad img file: ' . $image_file . ' ' . $function;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution, which uses curl to retrieve the image from a URL and then validates it:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $img_url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$img_data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($img_data);

if (!$img) {
    echo  "Invalid Image";
} else {
    echo  "Valid Image";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$external_link = ‘http://www.example.com/example.jpg’;
if (@getimagesize($external_link)) {
echo  “image exists “;
} else {
echo  “image does not exist “;
}
```

for more details 
[Check whether image exists on remote URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363925/check-whether-image-exists-on-remote-url)