# How to check if a file exist on an external server

Tags: php

How to check if a file exist on an External Server? I have a url "http://logs.com/logs/log.csv" and I have an script on another server to check if this file exists. I tried

```
$handle = fopen("http://logs.com/logs/log.csv","r");
if($handle === true){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
```

and

```
if(file_exists("http://logs.com/logs/log.csv")){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
```

These methos just do not work

Comment: try `if($handle)`. `$handle` won't be a boolean, so there's no point comparing it to one.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure error reporting is on.
2. Use `if($handle)`
3. Check [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is true.
4. If none of this works, use [this method on the file_exists page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#75064).

Answer (score 14):

```
function checkExternalFile($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $retCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $retCode;
}

$fileExists = checkExternalFile("http://example.com/your/url/here.jpg");

// $fileExists > 400 = not found
// $fileExists = 200 = found.
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://logs.com/logs/log.csv");

if (strlen($contents))
{
  return true; // yes it does exist
}
else
{
  return false; // oops
}
```

**Note:** This assumes file is not empty

Comment: What if the file exists but is empty?

Comment: This is going to be interesting if the file is quite large

Comment: @eithed true, but, thats the nature of the question.

Comment: @PhillHealey if you're quite happy to download entire file every time, then yes, I guess this is a solution - although I'd advocate for informing about potential drawbacks. Also `file_get_contents` relies on `allow_url_fopen`, so why not use `fopen` to begin with...

Comment: @eithed True, but then he is answering the question specifically in the sense that it is asked, and points arent awarded for answering more. That's not to say it's the best or most informative answer ever though.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 4file dir);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    preg_match_all("/HTTP\/1\.[1|0]\s(\d{3})/",$data,$matches); //check for HTTP headers

    $code = end($matches[1]);

    if(!$data) 
    {
        echo "file could not be found";
    } 
    else 
    {
        if($code == 200) 
        {
            echo "file found";
        } 
        elseif($code == 404) 
        {
            echo "file not found";
        }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: is there some way to diretcly grab the data for URLs which can just be called once when checked that they work?

Answer (score 0):

Requesting only headers will be much faster. I use this:

```
function isItAlive($url){ 
    stream_context_set_default(
        array(
            'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
            ],
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'HEAD'
            )
        )
      );
    $headers = @get_headers($url);
    $status = substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
    return ($status >= 200 && $status < 300 )?true:false;
}
```