# How to get final URL after following HTTP redirections in pure PHP?

Tags: php, http, http-headers

What I'd like to do is **find out what is the last/final URL after following the redirections**.

**I would prefer not to use cURL. I would like to stick with pure PHP (stream wrappers).**

Right now I have a URL (let's say http://domain.test), and I use get_headers() to get specific headers from that page. get_headers will also return multiple `Location:` headers (see ***Edit*** below). Is there a way to use those headers to build the final URL? or is there a PHP function that would automatically do this?

**Edit:** get_headers() follows redirections and returns all the headers for each response/redirections, so I have all the `Location:` headers.

Comment: There are *multiple* `Location:` headers in a single response?

Comment: get_headers does follow redirections automatically by defualt, so I get multiple `Location:` headers. What I'd like to have is the full final URL (http://domain.test/final/page.ext?attr...)

Comment: I did not understand the question :(

Comment: Try setting the `max_redirects` in the HTTP stream context to `1` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php). This should disable auto-redirecting and you can follow redirects yourself.

Comment: Is there a specification on how to build the next URL using the previously URL and a Location header?

Comment: @Webolde: Location header is defined as an absolute URI, but everyone and their dog uses relative URIs these days; so if it's an absolute URI, just redirect, if not, get domain+path of prev page, then make the new absolute URI from that and the Location field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Piskvor, that makes sense. I also found this on wikipedia, just for reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

Comment: @Webolde: ah, indeed, I forgot the citation: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
/**
 * get_redirect_url()
 * Gets the address that the provided URL redirects to,
 * or FALSE if there's no redirect. 
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string
 */
function get_redirect_url($url){
    $redirect_url = null; 

    $url_parts = @parse_url($url);
    if (!$url_parts) return false;
    if (!isset($url_parts['host'])) return false; //can't process relative URLs
    if (!isset($url_parts['path'])) $url_parts['path'] = '/';

    $sock = fsockopen($url_parts['host'], (isset($url_parts['port']) ? (int)$url_parts['port'] : 80), $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$sock) return false;

    $request = "HEAD " . $url_parts['path'] . (isset($url_parts['query']) ? '?'.$url_parts['query'] : '') . " HTTP/1.1\r\n"; 
    $request .= 'Host: ' . $url_parts['host'] . "\r\n"; 
    $request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"; 
    fwrite($sock, $request);
    $response = '';
    while(!feof($sock)) $response .= fread($sock, 8192);
    fclose($sock);

    if (preg_match('/^Location: (.+?)$/m', $response, $matches)){
        if ( substr($matches[1], 0, 1) == "/" )
            return $url_parts['scheme'] . "://" . $url_parts['host'] . trim($matches[1]);
        else
            return trim($matches[1]);

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * get_all_redirects()
 * Follows and collects all redirects, in order, for the given URL. 
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return array
 */
function get_all_redirects($url){
    $redirects = array();
    while ($newurl = get_redirect_url($url)){
        if (in_array($newurl, $redirects)){
            break;
        }
        $redirects[] = $newurl;
        $url = $newurl;
    }
    return $redirects;
}

/**
 * get_final_url()
 * Gets the address that the URL ultimately leads to. 
 * Returns $url itself if it isn't a redirect.
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string
 */
function get_final_url($url){
    $redirects = get_all_redirects($url);
    if (count($redirects)>0){
        return array_pop($redirects);
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

And, as always, give credit:

http://w-shadow.com/blog/2008/07/05/how-to-get-redirect-url-in-php/

Comment: You sir, just saved me few hours of searching. Everything works as expected.

Comment: I have to say that for my tests this solution with CURL is more reliable:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472329/php-get-url-of-redirect-from-source-url

Comment: I see fsockopen is set to port 80, does this not support a SSL/HTTPS 443 port redirect?

Answer (score 48):

```
function getRedirectUrl ($url) {
    stream_context_set_default(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD'
        )
    ));
    $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
    if ($headers !== false && isset($headers['Location'])) {
        return $headers['Location'];
    }
    return false;
}
```

***Additionally...***

As was mentioned in a comment, the *final* item in `$headers['Location']` will be your final URL after all redirects. It's important to note, though, that it won't *always* be an array. Sometimes it's just a run-of-the-mill, non-array variable. In this case, trying to access the last array element will most likely return a single character. Not ideal.

If you are only interested in the final URL, after all the redirects, I would suggest changing

```
return $headers['Location'];
```

to

```
return is_array($headers['Location']) ? array_pop($headers['Location']) : $headers['Location'];
```

... which is just [*if short-hand*](https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples) for

```
if(is_array($headers['Location'])){
     return array_pop($headers['Location']);
}else{
     return $headers['Location'];
}
```

This fix will take care of either case (array, non-array), and remove the need to weed-out the final URL after calling the function.

In the case where there are no redirects, the function will return `false`. Similarly, the function will also return `false` for invalid URLs (invalid for any reason). Therefor, it is important to [check the URL for validity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php?#answer-12628971) *before* running this function, or else incorporate the redirect check somewhere into your validation.

Comment: Does this follow all the redirections and returns the final URL?

Comment: Great yar.. Lot of time saved. +1

Comment: The marked answer to this question didn't follow all redirects. But this solution did.

Comment: `get_headers` follows all redirects and thus returns an array in `$headers[`Location']`; the last entry being the final URL

Comment: A note of caution on this answer. get_headers thinks `location` and `Location` are different headers. If you are following a chain of redirects which use different cases, you can't tell which header is the 'last' one, as you'll have urls in both `$headers['location']` and `$headers['Location']`

Comment: although it works fine beware of using this random in your code, because of the `stream_context_set_default` any following file operations like `file_get_contents` fail. A workaround would be to buffer the original context using `stream_context_get_default` and resetting it back to that when done.

Comment: Its not returning the final (last) redirected url

Answer (score 10):

While the OP wanted to avoid `cURL`, it's best to use it when it's available. Here's a solution which has the following advantages

- uses curl for all the heavy lifting, so works with https
- copes with servers which return lower cased `location` header name (both xaav and webjay's answers do not handle this)
- allows you to control how deep you want you go before giving up

Here's the function:

```
function findUltimateDestination($url, $maxRequests = 10)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $maxRequests);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

    //customize user agent if you desire...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Link Checker)');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_exec($ch);

    $url=curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

    curl_close ($ch);
    return $url;
}
```

Here's a more verbose version which allows you to inspect the redirection chain rather than let curl follow it.

```
function findUltimateDestination($url, $maxRequests = 10)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

    //customize user agent if you desire...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Link Checker)');

    while ($maxRequests--) {

        //fetch
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        //try to determine redirection url
        $location = '';
        if (in_array(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE), [301, 302, 303, 307, 308])) {
            if (preg_match('/Location:(.*)/i', $response, $match)) {
                $location = trim($match[1]);
            }
        }

        if (empty($location)) {
            //we've reached the end of the chain...
            return $url;
        }

        //build next url
        if ($location[0] == '/') {
            $u = parse_url($url);
            $url = $u['scheme'] . '://' . $u['host'];
            if (isset($u['port'])) {
                $url .= ':' . $u['port'];
            }
            $url .= $location;
        } else {
            $url = $location;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

As an example of redirection chain which this function handles, but the others do not, try this:

```
echo findUltimateDestination('http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.infsof.2016.05.005')
```

At the time of writing, this involves 4 requests, with a mixture of `Location` and `location` headers involved.

Comment: The 2nd function worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 3):

[xaav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195644/xaav) answer is very good; except for the following two issues:

- It does not support HTTPS protocol => The solution was proposed as a comment in the original site: http://w-shadow.com/blog/2008/07/05/how-to-get-redirect-url-in-php/
- Some sites will not work since they will not recognise the underlying user agent (client browser)
  => This is simply fixed by adding a User-agent header field: I added an Android user agent (you can find here http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php other user agent examples according you your need):

  $request .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30\r\n";

Here's the modified answer:

```
/**
 * get_redirect_url()
 * Gets the address that the provided URL redirects to,
 * or FALSE if there's no redirect. 
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string
 */
function get_redirect_url($url){
    $redirect_url = null; 

    $url_parts = @parse_url($url);
    if (!$url_parts) return false;
    if (!isset($url_parts['host'])) return false; //can't process relative URLs
    if (!isset($url_parts['path'])) $url_parts['path'] = '/';

    $sock = fsockopen($url_parts['host'], (isset($url_parts['port']) ? (int)$url_parts['port'] : 80), $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$sock) return false;

    $request = "HEAD " . $url_parts['path'] . (isset($url_parts['query']) ? '?'.$url_parts['query'] : '') . " HTTP/1.1\r\n"; 
    $request .= 'Host: ' . $url_parts['host'] . "\r\n"; 
    $request .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30\r\n";
    $request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"; 
    fwrite($sock, $request);
    $response = '';
    while(!feof($sock)) $response .= fread($sock, 8192);
    fclose($sock);

    if (preg_match('/^Location: (.+?)$/m', $response, $matches)){
        if ( substr($matches[1], 0, 1) == "/" )
            return $url_parts['scheme'] . "://" . $url_parts['host'] . trim($matches[1]);
        else
            return trim($matches[1]);

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * get_all_redirects()
 * Follows and collects all redirects, in order, for the given URL. 
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return array
 */
function get_all_redirects($url){
    $redirects = array();
    while ($newurl = get_redirect_url($url)){
        if (in_array($newurl, $redirects)){
            break;
        }
        $redirects[] = $newurl;
        $url = $newurl;
    }
    return $redirects;
}

/**
 * get_final_url()
 * Gets the address that the URL ultimately leads to. 
 * Returns $url itself if it isn't a redirect.
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string
 */
function get_final_url($url){
    $redirects = get_all_redirects($url);
    if (count($redirects)>0){
        return array_pop($redirects);
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 500 executing this script.

Comment: needs a } after the else condition on the the 3rd to last line

Comment: Damn none of the answers show more than 1 redirect :( even the curl ones

Answer (score 0):

Added to code from answers @xaav and @Houssem BDIOUI: 404 Error case and case when URL with no response. `get_final_url($url)` in that cases return strings: 'Error: 404 Not Found' and 'Error: No Responce'.

```
/**
 * get_redirect_url()
 * Gets the address that the provided URL redirects to,
 * or FALSE if there's no redirect,
 * or 'Error: No Responce',
 * or 'Error: 404 Not Found'
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string
 */
function get_redirect_url($url)
{
    $redirect_url = null;

    $url_parts = @parse_url($url);
    if (!$url_parts)
        return false;
    if (!isset($url_parts['host']))
        return false; //can't process relative URLs
    if (!isset($url_parts['path']))
        $url_parts['path'] = '/';

    $sock = @fsockopen($url_parts['host'], (isset($url_parts['port']) ? (int)$url_parts['port'] : 80), $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$sock) return 'Error: No Responce';

    $request = "HEAD " . $url_parts['path'] . (isset($url_parts['query']) ? '?' . $url_parts['query'] : '') . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $request .= 'Host: ' . $url_parts['host'] . "\r\n";
    $request .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36\r\n";
    $request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($sock, $request);
    $response = '';
    while (!feof($sock))
        $response .= fread($sock, 8192);
    fclose($sock);

    if (stripos($response, '404 Not Found') !== false)
    {
        return 'Error: 404 Not Found';
    }

    if (preg_match('/^Location: (.+?)$/m', $response, $matches))
    {
        if (substr($matches[1], 0, 1) == "/")
            return $url_parts['scheme'] . "://" . $url_parts['host'] . trim($matches[1]);
        else
            return trim($matches[1]);

    } else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * get_all_redirects()
 * Follows and collects all redirects, in order, for the given URL.
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return array
 */
function get_all_redirects($url)
{
    $redirects = array();
    while ($newurl = get_redirect_url($url))
    {
        if (in_array($newurl, $redirects))
        {
            break;
        }
        $redirects[] = $newurl;
        $url = $newurl;
    }
    return $redirects;
}

/**
 * get_final_url()
 * Gets the address that the URL ultimately leads to.
 * Returns $url itself if it isn't a redirect,
 * or 'Error: No Responce'
 * or 'Error: 404 Not Found',
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string
 */
function get_final_url($url)
{
    $redirects = get_all_redirects($url);
    if (count($redirects) > 0)
    {
        return array_pop($redirects);
    } else
    {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of reading Stackoverflow and trying out all custom functions written by people as well as trying all the cURL suggestions and nothing did more than 1 redirection, I managed to do a logic of my own which works.

```
$url = 'facebook.com';
// First let's find out if we just typed the domain name alone or we prepended with a protocol 
if (preg_match('/(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9_\/]*/',$url)) {
    $url = $url;
} else {
    $url = 'http://' . $url;
    echo '<p>No protocol given, defaulting to http://';
}
// Let's print out the initial URL
echo '<p>Initial URL: ' . $url . '</p>';
// Prepare the HEAD method when we send the request
stream_context_set_default(array('http' => array('method' => 'HEAD')));
// Probe for headers
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
// If there is a Location header, trigger logic
if (isset($headers['Location'])) {
    // If there is more than 1 redirect, Location will be array
    if (is_array($headers['Location'])) {
        // If that's the case, we are interested in the last element of the array (thus the last Location)
        echo '<p>Redirected URL: ' . $headers['Location'][array_key_last($headers['Location'])] . '</p>';
        $url = $headers['Location'][array_key_last($headers['Location'])];
    } else {
        // If it's not an array, it means there is only 1 redirect
        //var_dump($headers['Location']);
        echo '<p>Redirected URL: ' . $headers['Location'] . '</p>';
        $url = $headers['Location'];
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>URL: ' . $url . '</p>';
}
// You can now send get_headers to the latest location
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
```