# PHP Find the url a website is automanically reffering to?

Tags: php, url, refer

i`d like to get the url of an website, which an website is automatically referring to.
For example:
When i browse the link "www.example.de" it refers me automatically to "www.example.de/example123/example.php" (This one i`d like to get)

Unfortunetaly it is not possible to get the second link but using the first link.

Greeting,
Geigerkind

Comment: possible duplicate of [php get url of redirect from source url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472329/php-get-url-of-redirect-from-source-url)

Comment: Are you asking how to redirect `www.example.de` to `www.example.de/example123/example.php`?

Comment: That is exactly what i searched, thanks for the advice esqew. I did not find it on my own. Thanks you really saved my day!

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

(Sorry haven't got a PHP up to test on)

Comment: I dont know how this could give me the url of an external website, becuase $_SERVER returnes my url :/

Comment: Sorry presumed you were talking about your own site. You didn't specify it was an external website.