# Get redirect link from stream link in android

Tags: android, html, video

I have a stream video link: **http: //tv.zing.vn/html5/video/ZnJnyDJLiJyDnLn**

How do i can get redirect link of it in java android ?

(**http ://stream6.s1.tv.zdn.vn/streaming/0ff0be3df9194019d666c6a1f9e10001/53ac5d90/2013/0411/ff/d9ee4831b9f5c268a054e1f6c24b2415.mp4?format=f360&device=web_html5**)

Thanks for all idea :-)

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472329/php-get-url-of-redirect-from-source-url
PS: Your question is vague. What you want is not "direct link" (although in this case, it might be), but what the link redirects to.
:)

Comment: yes. It's redirects link :D
But your above link is for php. How do i can do in java android ?

Comment: Sorry about that. Don't know why I assumed you're a PHP programmer lol

Answer (score 0):

If have the development setup, through adb i think you might get the link from the logcat with,

```
adb logcat |grep -i source
```