# How to Convert Facebook fake user id to real user id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am building a Facebook app that will return users who like a product that a business would offer. I am using the Facebook Query Builder located here `https://github.com/SammyK/FacebookQueryBuilder` to do all of this.

The app is using the Facebook Graph Search API to return pages that match a certain search criteria. Then it looks at who has liked the recent statuses of that page, making them a "warm" lead. I get back a fake ID of a user. Test it out for yourself.

If you go to Facebook / 684351765016845 you will be redirected to facebook / arturo.valencia.37

But the real facebook user id is : 100003260838219 not 684351765016845.

I need to get either the real facebook user id or the user name which is what Facebook redirects to. I've even tried logging in with a curl request and trying to let it redirect me like that is shown here

[php get url of redirect from source url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472329/php-get-url-of-redirect-from-source-url?answertab=active#tab-top)

I'm not exactly sure what I need to do. Any help is appreciated.

You can see my test app  and the results I get back located here : 
`http://104.131.178.30/ryan/`

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since April 2014 (v2.0 of the Graph API), it´s not possible to get the "real" ID anymore, you only get an "App Scoped ID". It´s not a fake one, it´s unique in that specific App so you can still use it to identify returning users.

It´s not possible to get the "username" either anymore, as it would allow someone to get the real ID.

Check out the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog