# Php - Getting file size with an url

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get a file size of an image from a remote url, I am trying to this like so:

```
$remoteUrl = $file->guid;
//remote url example: http://myApp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Screen-Shot-2017-05-08-at-10.35.54.png  

$fileSize = filesize($remoteUrl);
```

But, I get:

> filesize(): stat failed for
>   http://myApp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Screen-Shot-2017-05-08-at-10.35.54.png

Comment: HTTP is not a file system.  You'd need to download the content from that URL (with something like CURL) and examine the size of that downloaded content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get size of a remote file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816849/get-size-of-a-remote-file)

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file)
It suggests curl for this task.

Answer (score 17):

You can use HTTP headers to find the size of the object. The PHP function `get_headers()` can get them:

```
$headers = get_headers('http://myApp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Screen-Shot-2017-05-08-at-10.35.54.png', true);
echo $headers['Content-Length'];
```

This way you can avoid downloading the entire file. You also have access to all other headers, such as `$headers['Content-Type']`, which can come in handy if you are dealing with images ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)).

Comment: Are you sure, We can get `Content-Length` from each file?

Comment: @PoojaJadav Acording to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) it has a permantent status, so you should expect this header on every response.

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means the supplied URL does not return a valid image. When I try to visit `http://myapp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Screen-Shot-2017-05-08-at-10.35.54.png` it does not show an image in my browser. Double check that the returned URL from `$file->guid;` is correct.

Comment: It's assuming, I know, but I figured the URL was fake and just an example URL when I saw it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to try a different method, the [**http://** stream wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) does not support `stat()` which is needed for the [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file) has some options you might use, using `curl` to make a `HEAD` request and inspect the `Content-Length` header.