# Get size of readfile transferred

Tags: php

I'm trying to stream a video file from a remote server to a client, and I want to get the size of the content transferred while the client plays the file, is it possible somehow?

```
$file = 'https://example.com/?rud27pxppu45zk.mp4';

$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($file, TRUE));
$size = $head['content-length']; // because filesize() won't work remotely

header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Disposition: inline');
header('Content-Length:'.$size);

readfile($file);

exit;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remote file size without downloading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/remote-file-size-without-downloading-file)

Comment: also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816849/get-size-of-a-remote-file

Comment: @CyC0der I already have the size as $size from headers. I need to get the size while client streams this file.

Comment: please explain it more

Comment: There is that file on some server, and the code above it's on my server. I want to get the size the client receives from the readfile function, the file it's inline.

Comment: readfile will read all bytes and return it to the bowser by one response header, its not possible or maybe i didn't get what do you mean