# Get actual linked url from hashed url using php

Tags: php

I have linkedin hashed urls and i want to get real urls from them. For example, below URL:

https://www.linkedin.com/in/AEEAAARQHxsBL619GKiV1lx06utiSyB2NVYrQLY

gets converted to https://www.linkedin.com/in/anaelis/

Is there any way of getting the second url from first using PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

You can request the hashed URL and get the redirect location.

Have a look here:
[php get url of redirect from source url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472329/php-get-url-of-redirect-from-source-url)

Comment: I checked the link but none of these solutions working for linked hashed urls.

Comment: It is the same mechanism: they redirect you to the real url, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes,i tired and it is giving below output which doesn't have the required url:

Comment: HTTP/1.1 999 Request denied Content-Length: 1461 Content-Type: text/html Set-Cookie: trkCode=bf; Max-Age=5 
Set-Cookie: trkInfo=AQGh2J7WYkTQDQAAAXI7dbuYvugSbifM4YxRV2rUqe8zS7NgVpwtp44HnuGYheFnIYyDo9ckUYl6BgrKGJr5_FleVaPtTMHd3aIrO8v3lYkE0dyMgIaMkTPbOCQWntWwdTQ_CTM=;
 Max-Age=5

Comment: It requires you to be logged in on your LinkedIn account, that's why it works on browser, try to go to that URL on a private browser window than you'll see. If you copy the whole request data (with cookies your browser sends) as `curl` than it works on CMD or bash.