# Get Facebook Profile URL From Facebook Profile id Using PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I have a list of Facebook links in xls sheet with Facebook id something like this
[image]

and when i go through these links means if i access Facebook with id [www.facebook.com/7500](https://www.facebook.com/7500)

i get urls something like this https://www.facebook.com/davesachs/

so my question is i want to do this with PHP, i have a PHP page which read data from xls sheet
my code here:

```
require_once 'src/SimpleXLSX.php';
if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('fburl.xlsx') ) {
$rows= $xlsx->rows();

foreach($rows as $data){
echo $data[0].'<br>';
}


} else {
echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
}
```

its returning all Facebook link with id same that i am passing like [www.facebook.com/7500](http://www.facebook.com/7500) but i want it return URL / link of profile as https://www.facebook.com/davesachs/ ,if it is possible please help me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that, Taken reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17473000/10302693)

```
<?php 

require_once 'src/SimpleXLSX.php';
if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('fburl.xlsx') ) {
$rows= $xlsx->rows();

foreach($rows as $data){
  getRedirectedUrl($data[0]);
}


} else {
echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
}


function getRedirectedUrl($link){
$url=$link;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Must be set to true so that PHP follows any "Location:" header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$a = curl_exec($ch); // $a will contain all headers

$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); // This is what you need, it will return you the last effective URL

// Uncomment to see all headers
/*
echo "<pre>";
print_r($a);echo"<br>";
echo "</pre>";
*/

echo $url; // Voila
}
?>
```

Comment: its returning unsupported browser and when i use ua  $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) \ 
Chrome/24.0.1304.0 Safari/537.16';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);  its returning the same url that i am passing not the result url i wanted