# simple_html_dom trying to parse the site, but the cat doesn't output anything

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to parse the site, but the cat doesn't output anything

```
<?php

include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://teleprogramma.pro/headlines'); 

foreach($html->find('.text-part') as $element) {
    echo $element->outertext;
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you try the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no Elements in the document which match the class `.text-part`. You can look at the source code when you save the HTML into a file.

```
<?php

include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://teleprogramma.pro/headlines'); 
file_put_contents('htmlData.html', $html);
```

When you try for example to find `.block-top-section-posts` you'll get a result.

```
<?php
    include_once 'simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php';
    
    $html = file_get_html('https://teleprogramma.pro/headlines'); 

    foreach($html->find('.block-top-section-posts') as $element) {
        echo $element->outertext;
    }

// Outputs
/* 
<div class="vue-container block-top-section-posts">     <div id="vuetag-top-section-posts" class="vue-tag news-line" data-url="/rest/term-additional-loading/section/76217/0/0" data-max-width="0" data-min-width="0" data-information="">            </div>   </div>
*/
```

---

When you lookup the Site in a Browser you will get redirected to another URL. If you want to use that, have a look at [php get url of redirect from source url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17473000/5841606) to get the final address.