# Is there a way I can get the redirect URL without loading the content?

Tags: php, rest, redirect

I am getting requests of a service (Beats Service to be specific) where I don't want to expose my client_id. I was able to hide it for everything except for a static image that can be retrieved using a client_id. So, here is the request:

https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/v1/api/tracks/tr58141709/images/default?client_id=XXXXXXX

when accessing this request, the url **redirects** to a static image. How can I retrieve the redirected URL without loading the content to my server (I just don't want to do it. It might be a very small overhead since the artwork size is small but I don't want to have it)?

I am using Guzzle as the Http Client for PHP but that is not my main concern because if I understand how this thing works without loading the content, I will be able to enforce what I want to Guzzle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get final URL after following HTTP redirections in pure PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799134/how-to-get-final-url-after-following-http-redirections-in-pure-php)

Comment: that url gives me `403 Forbidden` so I can't test against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using curl:

```
$url = 'https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/v1/api/tracks/tr58141709/images/default?client_id=XXXXXXX';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// check if we've received a redirect in the Location header
if (array_key_exists('redirect_url', $info)) {
        // do something with the Location header value
        echo $info['redirect_url'];
}
```

Comment: that still fetches the content, you need to make a 'HEAD' request instead of a 'GET' request.

Comment: I believe that the poster is worried about loading the content from the URL that is redirected to but moreover, a redirect in general (and this specific one for sure) does not return any content anyhow (since it would not be displayed anyway).

Comment: on top of that, using HEAD against his URL produces `< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Allow: GET`

Comment: you need to provide a valid client id (see returned html content! ;-))

Comment: Here is a client_id: *uu23r7kzmkref56e7nga4ejf*. I will delete it after this post. So I am going to apologize to the future readers :)