# Using get_headers to get the last HTTP interaction

Tags: html, redirect, video, mp4

I am trying to get the header url of the url the redirect me to a different page. I am not interested on the **original referrer**, my goal is to pull out the url of the **landing page** of the url I input. Below is an example of url that redirects me to different location. I have tried doing the code below but still no luck, it is just giving me errors

```
<?php
$url = "http://gateway.play44.net:3010/old/videos/one-punch_man_-_03.mp4?st=xV6C9jBU17ALqrMSAWriLA&e=1447624008&server=video44";

$headers = get_headers($url);

$code = $headers[0];
?>
```

**Original Referrer**

http://gateway.play44.net:3010/old/videos/one-punch_man_-_03.mp4?st=xV6C9jBU17ALqrMSAWriLA&e=1447624008&server=video44

**Landing Page of the original referrer** (I want to pull this on out using the original referrer)

http://s3.videobug.net/O/one-punch_man_-_03.mp4?st=k99nV8wxJ8nuqiDVWzFMqg&e=1447624008&start=0

Comment: For me it redirects to http://s7.videobug.net/O/one-punch_man_-_03.mp4?st=k99nV8wxJ8nuqiDVWzFMqg&e=1447624008&start=0

Comment: It changes, I only want to get the landing page url

Comment: Do you have access to the server administration? If you don't surely there's nothing that you can do as it the redirect is done from the server side (by opening DevTools we can see that the server is sending a 302 "Temporarily Moved" response which can't be ignored by your browser).

Comment: I have updated my question above to make it more clear to you

Comment: You may be looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799134/how-to-get-final-url-after-following-http-redirections-in-pure-php

Comment: I love you! This one works great!