# How to send an incomplete HTTP request from PHP?

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I need to check if remote file are online and they didn't change. The problem is that those files are big, so I want to read the http header only and then abort the request. The result would be based on response status code and content length field.

How can I do it in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if an URL exists in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/check-if-an-url-exists-in-php)

Comment: more http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=check+if+link+exists+php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) function.

If you prefer [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), you can use `CURLOPT_NOBODY`:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$headers = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: There are subtle (but potentially important) differences between these two methods. `get_headers()` sends a normal GET request and destroys the connection as soon as the head has been recieved. cURL with `...NOBODY` sends a HEAD request. The cURL method is slightly quicker, but may also return an incomplete/incorrect picture, depending on the object you request and the server you request it from. Neither of these will allow you to peform anything other than a GET request and return just the head (HEAD is supposed to simulate a GET).

Comment: cURL example wasn't working, I found out that `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); ` was missing.