# How can i check whether the given url exists or not in php?

Tags: php

I have URL like this "**http://example.com/index.php?id=10**". How can i check whether this URL exists or not?

Comment: You can curl the page or use file_get_contents() function

Comment: How about check if similar questions exists or not in SO...! See this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/check-if-an-url-exists-in-php

Comment: Just to be pedantic. Do you really want to check if it exists? Or if it exists without redirection, or if you are authorized to access it? (it might exist, but you are not allowed access)    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`get_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) function.

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';    
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);

if ($headers !== false && substr($headers[0], 9, 3) == 200) {
    echo 'Page exists';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the website is properly set up, you should get a `200 OK` status code if the URL exists and you are allowed to see it. You can check this with curl:

```
$http = curl_init("http://example.com/index.php?id=10");
curl_exec($http);
$responseCode = curl_getinfo($http, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($responseCode == 200)
    //Page exists
```

*Code not tested*

Comment: +1 but ... I think you mean "200 OK status code if the URL exists *and you are authorized to access it (etc)*". The OP _says_ he wants to check if it exists (which your code won't correctly check if he is not allowed to access it). Your code answers his question as asked. I just wonder if it is really what he wanted to ask (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Comment: ah true, clarifying it in the answer