# MySQL/PHP best way of cleaning/validating URLs stored in db

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DB with URLs of manufacturers collected in the last years and I need to do some spring cleaning:

1. Some urls are like `http://brandname.com/aboutus/`
   so i need to remove any path other than just the main domain, because many of those path/subdirectory may have expired...
2. I would love to be able to check if those domain actually exists anymore or are taken by domain sharks...

I'm currently using PHP+MySQL

Comment: Well, what is your question here? Obviously you need to take the URLs one by one, use `parse_url()` to pick the tokens you need, so scheme and hostname here, and then make a test request. I'd even say that you are not at all interested in the domains, but in the hostnames, since a domain without web service most likely is without value to you...

Comment: Use regular expression http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url

Comment: @arkascha thanks for pointing me to parse_url!

Comment: @Suraj Regular expressions are only a last means if no better matching function exists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a function for doing what you ask, with references to Stack Overflow answers which give the details you need.

**First:**
Parse the URL using the PHP standard `filter_var` [Validate](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) (and [Sanitise](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)) functions. You may also need to ensure that the scheme is properly defined.

**Second,**
Run a PHP cURL request to get the HTTP header of the full URL and then of the site URL. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12629254/3536236).

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/folder/file.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // we want headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);    // we don't need body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

echo 'HTTP code: ' . $httpcode;
```

**Third**
If the `$httpcode` returns a 200 then it's good working link, else we need to cut the link down to just the site and recheck if the site (still) exists. You can do this using [Parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276525/3536236).

```
so: 
if($httpcode == 200){
    //works
}
if($httpcode >= 400 ){
     /*** errors 400+ ***/
    $siteUrlParts = parse_url($url);
    $siteUrl = $siteUrlParts['scheme']."//".$siteUrlParts['host'];
}
else {
   //some other header, up to you how you want to handle this.
   // could be a redirect 302 or something...  
}
```

Note the `schema` part is important not just the `host` part.

**Fourth**
That's it, update the database row with the new working URL.

## All Together:

```
function get_header_code($url){
    /*** 
     cURL
     ***/
    $ch = curl_init($link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // we want headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);    // we don't need body
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $httpCode;
}

function clean_url($link){
    $link = strtolower($link);
    $link = filter_var($link, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

    if(substr($link,0,8) !== "https://" && substr($link,0,7) !== "http://"){
        $link = "http://".$link;
    }

    if(filter_var($link, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE){
    /***
     Invalid URL so clean and remove.
     ***/
    return false;
    }
    $httpCode = get_header_code($link);

    if($httpCode == 200){
      /***
       works, so return full URL
       ***/
      return $link;
    }
    if($httpcode >= 400 ){
     /*** errors 400+ ***/
        $siteUrlParts = parse_url($link);
        $siteUrl = $siteUrlParts['scheme']."://".$siteUrlParts['host'];
        if(get_header_code($siteUrl) == 200){
             /***
              Obviously you can add conditionals to accept if it is a
              redirection but this is a basic example
              ***/  
             return $siteUrl;
        }
        return false;
    }
    else {
       /***
        some other header, up to you how you want to handle this.
        could be a redirect 301, 302 or something... 
        ***/
       return false; 
    }

}
```

And run it as:

```
/***
 returns either false or the URL of a working domain from the Db.
 ***/
$updateValueUrl = clean_url($databaseRow['url']);
```

This is probably not quite perfect for you but should give you a good grounding from which to make your desired behaviour. Once this is in place you then can run a PHP MySQL loop to grab every URL (in `LIMIT` batches of maybe 500 or 1000) at a time and loop through each one using  `foreach` and updating each with the output from these functions.