# PHP check youtube channel existence without API

Tags: php, youtube

I want to make simple `curl` call to check if youtube channel exists.
Is it possible without using google API ?

Answer (score -1):

Yep, just using cURL, if you try to access a non-existent YouTube Channel, say https://www.youtube.com/channel/hello, it responds with a status code of 404. You can use that to find if the channel exists or not.

The above is the logic and to find it using cURL, you may check:

- [Getting HTTP code in PHP using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797680/getting-http-code-in-php-using-curl)
- [How can I check if a URL exists via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php/12628971#12628971)

Comment: well curl responds 200. why it is marked as duplicate ? and linked to question not related to youtube channel..

Comment: I know how to make a curl request.. which I am doing for many different urls, but problem I have only with youtube channel. thats what Ive asked, and my question was marked as duplicate + got two minuses.. great.

Comment: @Baku Even I have got a minus in the answer. But yea, weird how cURL returns 200.

Comment: probably without parsing response no luck

Comment: @Baku Weird... Did you check the network tools? I get 404...

Comment: yes Ive checked. heh strange.

Comment: ah channel hello I get by curl 404, but for example https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbS8vsbx1MSl1aGrja2-4kz I see 200